# How to check if a service is running on Android?

Tags: android, android-service

How do I check if a background service is running?

I want an Android activity that toggles the state of the service -- it lets me turn it on if it is off and off if it is on.

Comment: Check out [this german guide](http://www.androidpit.de/de/android/forum/thread/221112/Wie-Pruefen-ob-ein-Service-bereits-laeuft).

Comment: the correct answer is below and not the one marked: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5921190/2369122

Comment: @toidiu If that hasn't already been nerfed like `getRunningTasks()`, it probably will be.

Comment: using the getSystemService() function you can retrieve all the running services. loop through it and check the your service exist in the list here you can see a small sample http://wiki.workassis.com/android-check-the-service-is-running/

Answer (score 315, accepted):

I had the same problem not long ago. Since my service was local, I ended up simply using a static field in the service class to toggle state, as described by hackbod [here](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/8c4bd731681b8331/bf3ae8ef79cad75d)

**EDIT (for the record):**

Here is the solution proposed by hackbod:

> If your client and server code is part of the same .apk and you are 
>   binding to the service with a concrete Intent (one that specifies the 
>   exact service class), then you can simply have your service set a 
>   global variable when it is running that your client can check.
>
> We deliberately don't have an API to check whether a service is 
>   running because, nearly without fail, when you want to do something 
>   like that you end up with race conditions in your code.

Comment: This will be faster to execute then the answer by @geekQ (now the most highly rated), but I wonder whether the reference to the Service will cause that class to be included in the Receiver component - which should be kept as small as possible.

Comment: @Pacerier, the solution you reference requires starting the service and I think the best flexible solution should allow you to check whether a service is running without starting it.

Comment: +1 This method is more sustainable. The one offered by @geekQ does not work on Android KitKat.

Comment: This solution only works for local services. @geekQ solution works on any version of Android and actually works whether the service is local or not.

Comment: What about if the service is stopped by the system, how do you detect that and toggle your variable?

Comment: When the app is killed, the service that it had started is also killed but the service's `onDestroy()` is not called. So the static variable cannot be updated in such a scenario resulting in inconsistent behaviour.

Comment: @faizal Wouldn't the static variable also be re-intialized, thus setting it back to the default value that indicates the service is no longer running?

Comment: @PabloC you are right. I stand corrected. If the static variable is a boolean(or equivalent type with only 2 possible values), it should not be a problem. But suppose that only the service is killed, while the app is not. This happens pretty often with background services. In that case, the common process that hosts both the app and the service, is not killed. So the static variable in the service class will not be re-initialized and reading this variable in the app now will be erroneous.

Comment: @faizal Ok, would onDestroy() on the service be called in that case?

Comment: @PabloC `onDestroy()` will not be called if the service is terminated by the OS unexpectedly. See https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/2DTkEk73xpk.

Comment: @faizal, local Service is not a separate process, so if service is killed then app also will kill.

Comment: @Sever that's an interesting point. So static variable is the best solution then!

Comment: and what about multi process apps

Comment: @haresh: Thank you for the answer. Let's say I initiated the service on a button click., Goes out of the activity so the activity is destroyed now. I recreated the activity. Now how to check if the service is running or not. If running then how to stop it. Please suggest something else other than ActivityManager list. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @kaushik Please refer your question to miracle2k instead.

Comment: The hackbod link seems to be dead, Someone please update it.

Comment: The hackbod link seems to be dead, Someone please update it.

Comment: @miracle2k link is dead

Comment: @Sever Going from the likelihood of something being killed, the background activity is going to be killed quicker than a foreground service, but a foreground activity might stay longer than the foreground service and activities and services can be destroyed by android independently of the whole app process.

Answer (score 1786):

I use the following from inside an activity:

```
private boolean isMyServiceRunning(Class<?> serviceClass) {
    ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    for (RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
        if (serviceClass.getName().equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

And I call it using:

```
isMyServiceRunning(MyService.class)
```

This works reliably, because it is based on the information about running services provided by the Android operating system through [`ActivityManager#getRunningServices`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#getRunningServices%28int%29).

All the approaches using `onDestroy` or `onSomething` events or Binders or static variables will not work reliably because as a developer you never know, when Android decides to kill your process or which of the mentioned callbacks are called or not. Please note the "killable" column in the [lifecycle events table](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle) in the Android documentation.

Comment: Presumably this requires the permission to view running applications and services? Not ideal.

Comment: Thanks for this solution. I'd like to add: Instead "com.example.MyService" is more elegant to use MyService.class.getName()

Comment: ACTIVITY_SERVICE is not defined in Eclipse for the API 10. Do I missed something ?

Comment: Personally, I went with using a static field. Although using getRunningServices() is a more robust solution, I believe there is in these two solutions a tradeoff between robustness and efficiency/simplicity. If you need to check frequently whether a service is running, looping through potentially 30+ running services is not very ideal. The rare case of a service being destroyed by the system can be handled perhaps by a try/catch block or by using START_STICKY.

Comment: No it isn't the right answer because it's also written in the docs: "Note: this method is only intended for debugging or implementing service management type user interfaces."  It's not meant for control flow!

Comment: People find it elegant to have to go through all that to check if a server is running?

Comment: Apparently this does not work with ServiceTestCase when writing Android unit tests. Not sure what works differently. The service never seems to get added. However, you can unit test this functionality with a normal AndroidTestCase and just call getContext().startService(intent);

Comment: @seb This is definitely for a service management UI since the question is how to manage (I.E. toggle) a service.

Comment: This code is incorrect/incomplete. It also needs to check for the package name, as currently there is a chance you'll find services from other packages rather than your own.

Comment: I think static field is a better solution. if a service bound in an activity this method returns true whether service not started yet.

Comment: -1. This method is not really sustainable. It does not work on Android KitKat.

Comment: Calling `bindService` with `0` as flag does not start the service, but this method identifies it as running.

Comment: This does not work in one particular case. When the app is killed, the service that it had started is also killed. But this function will still return true in the activity's onDestroy() method. So it is not reliable in this scenario.

Comment: @seb docs are written by humans and sometime deliberately to keep them away. but that's the only way to know if a `Service` is running so you won't start it again and again. Also it is helpful in the case if a user has `Force Stop` your app *intentionally/unintentionally*!

Comment: I'd discourage the use of this solution. For Android L [they're removing](https://developer.android.com/preview/api-overview.html#Behaviors) ActivityManager.getRecentTasks() and it had the same note in the documentation. So be warned!

Comment: This seems to find services that have been stopped as well as running services. Perhaps `return service.started;` improves upon `return true;`?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `<? extends Service>` so it's harder to call it with the wrong argument?

Comment: It does not work when user exit app with home button, then when user back to app onCreate this method return true even Service is not running

Comment: @Andreas Schildbach getName() and getClassName() return the full qualified class name with package name so chance of name collision is practically nil.

Comment: So you will list down all the services running on the device and compare with your service ? Is this a optimum solution ? Really ! Down voted

Comment: Starting **Android O**, `getRunningServices` is deprecated. This answer needs an update for newer version.

Comment: _For backwards compatibility, it will still return the caller's own services._
This means we could still use it for this purpose right ? @poring91

Comment: @poring91 as of **Android O**, `getRunningServices` is no longer available to **third party** applications. For backwards compatibility, it will **still return the caller's own services**.

Comment: As seb says ActivityManager should be used only for testing and debugging. This is not the right answer!!

Comment: fix error here:    for (ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo service

Comment: @geekQ will this work even for checking the remote services?

Comment: On phone with many app, looping through all running services may take long time.

Answer (score 81):

Got it!

You **MUST** call `startService()` for your service to be properly registered and passing `BIND_AUTO_CREATE` will not suffice.

```
Intent bindIntent = new Intent(this,ServiceTask.class);
startService(bindIntent);
bindService(bindIntent,mConnection,0);
```

And now the ServiceTools class:

```
public class ServiceTools {
    private static String LOG_TAG = ServiceTools.class.getName();

    public static boolean isServiceRunning(String serviceClassName){
        final ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager)Application.getContext().getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        final List<RunningServiceInfo> services = activityManager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE);

        for (RunningServiceInfo runningServiceInfo : services) {
            if (runningServiceInfo.service.getClassName().equals(serviceClassName)){
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
     }
}
```

Comment: This will list just system services, no?! So my local service is excluded from list and I will get false ;(

Comment: This works with external services, for local services is pretty obvious if you're running.

Comment: Sorry but I need to say that is super silly answer..Why it is super obvious?!

Comment: For a local service, if you're application is running the service is as well. If it crashes it will take your application along with it.

Comment: Not clear what u mean here... Who was talking about crashing at all?! I am not interesting in crashing it. Service can be started, stopped, maybe it was intent service and it will stop on it's own when it is done... Question is how to know if it is still running or not after 3 min for example.

Comment: Not works because always call this service everytime! bad logical

Comment: It is incorrect to give the impression that a bound service must also be started. NO. Bind auto create does exactly what it says. It will create (and therefore "start") the service if the service is not yet running.

Answer (score 67):

A small complement is:

My goal is to know wether a service is running without actualy running it if it is not running.

Calling bindService or calling an intent that can be caught by the service is not a good idea then as it will start the service if it is not running.

So, as miracle2k suggested, the best is to have a static field in the service class to know whether the service has been started or not.

To make it even cleaner, I suggest to transform the service in a singleton with a very very lazy fetching: that is, there is no instantiation at all of the [singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) instance through static methods. The static getInstance method of your service/singleton just returns the instance of the singleton if it has been created. But it doesn't actualy start or instanciate the singleton itself. The service is only started through normal service start methods.

It would then be even cleaner to modify the singleton design pattern to rename the confusing getInstance method into something like the `isInstanceCreated() : boolean` method.

The code will look like:

```
public class MyService extends Service
{
   private static MyService instance = null;

   public static boolean isInstanceCreated() {
      return instance != null;
   }//met

   @Override
   public void onCreate()
   {
      instance = this;
      ....
   }//met

   @Override
   public void onDestroy()
   {
      instance = null;
      ...
   }//met
}//class
```

This solution is elegant, but it is only relevant if you have access to the service class and only for classes iside the app/package of the service. If your classes are outside of the service app/package then you could query the ActivityManager with limitations underlined by Pieter-Jan Van Robays.

Comment: This is flawed. onDestroy is not guaranteed to be called.

Comment: Why not, someone still has to call stop to stop a service, and it will cause onDestroy to be called.

Comment: When the system is low on memory, your service will be killed automatically without a call to your onDestroy, Which is why i say that this is flawed.

Comment: @Pacerier, but if the system kills the process, then the instance flag will still get reset.  I'm guessing that when the receiver next gets loaded (post the system killing the service) the static flag 'instance' will get recreated as null.

Comment: How cuold we verify that. And @Pacerier statement that onDestroy won't be called

Comment: At least better than iterating through all those services in isMyServiceRunning which really delays stuff if done on every device rotation :)

Comment: Your instance variable should not be declared final, otherwise it cannot be set or null'ed by the onCreate() or onDestroy() methods.

Comment: I rather liked this answer cause i can implement it so easy with just one of my existing variables set in onCreate() and easily skip it. Thanks man.

Comment: Check my solution below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48342923/1219213. It covers that part.

Answer (score 30):

You can use this (I didn't try this yet, but I hope this works):

```
if(startService(someIntent) != null) {
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Service is already running", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
else {
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "There is no service running, starting service..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

The startService method returns a ComponentName object if there is an already running service. If not, null will be returned.

See *[public abstract ComponentName startService (Intent service)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#startService%28android.content.Intent%29)*.

This is not like checking I think, because it's starting the service, so you can add `stopService(someIntent);` under the code.

Comment: Not exactly what the docs say. According to your link: "Returns
If the service is being started or is already running, the ComponentName of the actual service that was started is returned; else if the service does not exist null is returned."

Comment: Nice thinking ... but doesn't fit in current situation .

Comment: its not proper way, because when IDE trigger `if(startService(someIntent) != null)` that will check that `IsserviceRunning` but that will also play new service.

Comment: As it is stated, if you stop the service after this control it will be handy for this problem. But why to start and stop a service for nothing?

Comment: this will start the service, isn't it? Just want to check the status of service instead of starting it...

Answer (score 29):

```
/**
 * Check if the service is Running 
 * @param serviceClass the class of the Service
 *
 * @return true if the service is running otherwise false
 */
public boolean checkServiceRunning(Class<?> serviceClass){
    ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    for (RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE))
    {
        if (serviceClass.getName().equals(service.service.getClassName()))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 28):

An extract from **Android** docs:

> Like [sendBroadcast(Intent)](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/localbroadcastmanager/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html#sendBroadcast(android.content.Intent)), but if there are any receivers for
> the Intent this function will block and immediately dispatch them
> before returning.

*Think of this hack as "pinging" the `Service`*. Since we can broadcast synchronously, we can broadcast and get a result *synchronously*, on the UI thread.

### `Service`

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
   LocalBroadcastManager
     .getInstance(this)
     .registerReceiver(new ServiceEchoReceiver(), new IntentFilter("ping"));
     //do not forget to deregister the receiver when the service is destroyed to avoid
     //any potential memory leaks 
}

private class ServiceEchoReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public void onReceive (Context context, Intent intent) {
      LocalBroadcastManager
         .getInstance(this)
         .sendBroadcastSync(new Intent("pong"));
    }
}
```

### `Activity`

```
    bool serviceRunning = false;

    protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState){
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(pong, new IntentFilter("pong"));
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcastSync(new Intent("ping"));
        if(!serviceRunning){
           //run the service
        }
    }
    
    private BroadcastReceiver pong = new BroadcastReceiver(){
        public void onReceive (Context context, Intent intent) {
          serviceRunning = true;   
        }
    }
```

The winner in many applications is of course a static boolean field on the service that is set to `true` in `Service.onCreate()` and to `false` in `Service.onDestroy()` because it's a lot simpler.

Comment: This is a much better solution than the accepted one, which fails if Android kills the service since the global variable method would still indicate that the service is running when it actually no longer is. This synchronous ping-pong broadcast trick is actually the ONLY reliable method to check if a service is alive. It alone allows you to simply ASK the service if it is there. If it answers then the service is alive and running, if not it has either not been started or has been shut down, either programatically or by the system to recover memory.

Comment: LocalBroadcastManager is deprecated: https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/localbroadcastmanager/content/LocalBroadcastManager

Answer (score 18):

Another approach using kotlin. Inspired in other users answers

```
fun isMyServiceRunning(serviceClass: Class<*>): Boolean {
    val manager = getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE) as ActivityManager
    return manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)
            .any { it.service.className == serviceClass.name }
}
```

**As kotlin extension**

```
fun Context.isMyServiceRunning(serviceClass: Class<out Service>) = try {
    (getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE) as ActivityManager)
        .getRunningServices(Int.MAX_VALUE)
        .any { it.service.className == serviceClass.name }
} catch (e: Exception) {
    false
}
```

**Usage**

```
context.isMyServiceRunning(MyService::class.java)
```

Comment: NOTE: `getRunningServices` is now deprecated, through it seems the method won't be deleted.

Comment: As of Build.VERSION_CODES.O, this method is no longer available to third party applications. BUT, for backwards compatibility, it will still return the caller's own services.

Answer (score 15):

The proper way to check if a service is running is to simply ask it. Implement a BroadcastReceiver in your service that responds to pings from your activities. Register the BroadcastReceiver when the service starts, and unregister it when the service is destroyed. From your activity (or any component), send a [local broadcast](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html) intent to the service and if it responds, you know it's running. Note the subtle difference between ACTION_PING and ACTION_PONG in the code below.

```
public class PingableService extends Service {
    public static final String ACTION_PING = PingableService.class.getName() + ".PING";
    public static final String ACTION_PONG = PingableService.class.getName() + ".PONG";

    public int onStartCommand (Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mReceiver, new IntentFilter(ACTION_PING));
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy () {
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    private BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive (Context context, Intent intent) {
            if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_PING)) {
                LocalBroadcastManager manager = LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
                manager.sendBroadcast(new Intent(ACTION_PONG));
            }
        }
    };
}

public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    private boolean isSvcRunning = false;

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        LocalBroadcastManager manager = LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
        manager.registerReceiver(mReceiver, new IntentFilter(PingableService.ACTION_PONG));
        // the service will respond to this broadcast only if it's running
        manager.sendBroadcast(new Intent(PingableService.ACTION_PING));
        super.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
        super.onStop();
    }

    protected BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive (Context context, Intent intent) {
            // here you receive the response from the service
            if (intent.getAction().equals(PingableService.ACTION_PONG)) {
                isSvcRunning = true;
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: I actually like this approach.  It's a little heavy code wise but will always work.  I don't see broadcast intents being deprecated any time soon :)

Comment: Take into account that a broadcast can be missed.

Comment: And ...[LocalBroadcastManager is now deprecated](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/localbroadcastmanager/content/LocalBroadcastManager)... (rimshot). It's still a good solution though.

Comment: Well, this never returns "service is not running", so not really suitable for a lot of use cases...

Comment: You are not supposed to add code to a class just for testing purposes. So many of these dumb hacks on this thread.

Answer (score 14):

I have slightly modified one of the solutions presented above, but passing the class instead of a generic string name, in order to be sure to compare strings coming out from the same method `class.getName()`

```
public class ServiceTools {
    private static String LOG_TAG = ServiceTools.class.getName();

    public static boolean isServiceRunning(Context context,Class<?> serviceClass){
        final ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        final List<RunningServiceInfo> services = activityManager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE);

        for (RunningServiceInfo runningServiceInfo : services) {
            Log.d(Constants.TAG, String.format("Service:%s", runningServiceInfo.service.getClassName()));
            if (runningServiceInfo.service.getClassName().equals(serviceClass.getName())){
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

and then

```
Boolean isServiceRunning = ServiceTools.isServiceRunning(
                    MainActivity.this.getApplicationContext(),
                    BackgroundIntentService.class);
```

Comment: to be more on strict side you can change class param to `Class<? extends Service>`

Answer (score 9):

First of all you shouldn't reach the service by using the [`ActivityManager`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager). (Discussed [here](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/8c4bd731681b8331/bf3ae8ef79cad75d))

Services can run on their own, be bound to an Activity or both. The way to check in an Activity if your Service is running or not is by making an interface (that extends Binder) where you declare methods that both, the `Activity` and the `Service`, understand. You can do this by making your own Interface where you declare for example "`isServiceRunning()`".
You can then bind your Activity to your Service, run the method isServiceRunning(), the Service will check for itself if it is running or not and returns a boolean to your Activity.

You can also use this method to stop your Service or interact with it in another way.

Comment: That discussion took place on '12/26/07'.  Either that's July of this year (i.e. in the future), or that's before Android was even public.  Either way that makes me not trust it.

Comment: That discussion is from December 26, 2007. They are discussing a pre-release version I think (http://developer.android.com/sdk/OLD_RELEASENOTES.html#m3-rc37a) which was released on December 14, 2007.

Answer (score 9):

I just want to add a note to the answer by @Snicolas. The following steps can be used to check stop service with/without calling `onDestroy()`.

1. `onDestroy()` called: Go to Settings -> Application -> Running Services -> Select and stop your service.
2. `onDestroy()` not Called: Go to Settings -> Application -> Manage Applications -> Select and "Force Stop" your application in which your service is running. However, as your application is stopped here, so definitely the service instances will also be stopped.

Finally, I would like to mention that the approach mentioned there using a static variable in singleton class is working for me.

Comment: The service could be on different processes, take this into account

Answer (score 9):

Again, another alternative that people might find cleaner if they use pending intents (for instance with the `AlarmManager`:

```
public static boolean isRunning(Class<? extends Service> serviceClass) {
    final Intent intent = new Intent(context, serviceClass);
    return (PendingIntent.getService(context, CODE, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE) != null);
}
```

Where `CODE` is a constant that you define privately in your class to identify the pending intents associated to your service.

Comment: Combined or update your previous answer. Please refrain from posting more than one answers per post.

Comment: Can this answer be expanded on, i.e. how does one associate the value for CODE with the service?

Comment: Where to get context?

Answer (score 8):

`onDestroy` isn't always called in the service so this is useless!

For example: Just run the app again with one change from Eclipse. The application is forcefully exited using SIG: 9.

Answer (score 8):

Below is an elegant hack that covers all the `Ifs`. This is for local services only.

```
    public final class AService extends Service {

        private static AService mInstance = null;

        public static boolean isServiceCreated() {
            try {
                // If instance was not cleared but the service was destroyed an Exception will be thrown
                return mInstance != null && mInstance.ping();
            } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                // destroyed/not-started
                return false;
            }
        }

        /**
         * Simply returns true. If the service is still active, this method will be accessible.
         * @return
         */
        private boolean ping() {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate() {
            mInstance = this;
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroy() {
            mInstance = null;
        }
    }
```

And then later on:

```
    if(AService.isServiceCreated()){
        ...
    }else{
        startService(...);
    }
```

Comment: The only problem with this is if the service is a Sticky service and it restarts itself. Calling to isServiceCreated() will return false after the service starts again because mInstance will be null.

Comment: Wouldn't onCreate be called then when the service restarts itself?

Answer (score 7):

Xamarin C# version:

```
private bool isMyServiceRunning(System.Type cls)
{
    ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager)GetSystemService(Context.ActivityService);

    foreach (var service in manager.GetRunningServices(int.MaxValue)) {
        if (service.Service.ClassName.Equals(Java.Lang.Class.FromType(cls).CanonicalName)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: You need the ´Context` for [`GetSystemService`](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Android.Content.Context.GetSystemService/).

Answer (score 6):

For the use-case given here we may simply make use of the `stopService()` method's return value. It returns `true` if there exists the specified service and it is killed. Else it returns `false`. So you may restart the service if the result is `false` else it is assured that the current service has been stopped. :) It would be better if you have a look at [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#stopService%28android.content.Intent%29).

Answer (score 3):

> The response of geekQ but in Kotlin class. Thanks geekQ

```
fun isMyServiceRunning(serviceClass : Class<*> ) : Boolean{
    var manager = getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE) as ActivityManager
    for (service in manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
        if (serviceClass.name.equals(service.service.className)) {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

The call

```
isMyServiceRunning(NewService::class.java)
```

Comment: `ActivityManager.getRunningServices` is deprecated since Android O

Answer (score 3):

In your Service Sub-Class Use a Static Boolean to get the state of the Service as demonstrated below.

MyService.kt

```
class MyService : Service() {
    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        isServiceStarted = true
    }
    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        isServiceStarted = false
    }
    companion object {
        var isServiceStarted = false
    }
}
```

MainActivity.kt

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(){
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val serviceStarted = FileObserverService.isServiceStarted
        if (!serviceStarted) {
            val startFileObserverService = Intent(this, FileObserverService::class.java)
            ContextCompat.startForegroundService(this, startFileObserverService)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

For kotlin, you can use the below code.

```
fun isMyServiceRunning(calssObj: Class<SERVICE_CALL_NAME>): Boolean {
    val manager = requireActivity().getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE) as ActivityManager
    for (service in manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
        if (calssObj.getName().equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

Comment: This is a great answer for writing tests, since you can use it without changing your working code.

Comment: can we make this return  Flow<Boolean> ?

Comment: Why use `equals` for Kotlin here?

Answer (score 3):

In kotlin you can add boolean variable in companion object and check its value from any class you want:

```
companion object{
     var isRuning = false

}
```

Change it value when service is created and destroyed

```
 override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        isRuning = true
    }

override fun onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy()
    isRuning = false
    }
```

Comment: onDestroy() is not always called

Comment: @user924 When `onDestroy()` is not called, it is because the whole process is killed, so there is nothing around that can check the value of `isRuning`.  In fact, `isRuning` does not exist any longer at this point. So it is not a problem that `onDestroy()` is not called. This is assuming all components live in the same process, of course (which is the default).

Answer (score 2):

Inside TheServiceClass define:

```
 public static Boolean serviceRunning = false;
```

Then In onStartCommand(...)

```
 public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    serviceRunning = true;
    ...
}

 @Override
public void onDestroy()
{
    serviceRunning = false;

}
```

Then, call `if(TheServiceClass.serviceRunning == true)` from any class.

Comment: This doesn't work if you service gets killed by Android.

Comment: @Heisenberg I just experienced that myself. Do you know why not?

Comment: @Heisenberg when my app is killed by OS, the service does restart and sets the static bool to true, but upon getting it it reports false

Comment: this won't work if you call `stopService`. At least for Intent services. `onDestroy()` will be called immediately, but `onHandleIntent()` will still be running

Comment: @Heisenberg  Won't killing the service due to low memory also mean killing the process?

Answer (score 2):

<strike>**simple use bind with don't create auto**</strike> - see ps. and update...

```
public abstract class Context {

 ... 

  /*
  * @return {true} If you have successfully bound to the service, 
  *  {false} is returned if the connection is not made 
  *  so you will not receive the service object.
  */
  public abstract boolean bindService(@RequiresPermission Intent service,
        @NonNull ServiceConnection conn, @BindServiceFlags int flags);
```

example :

```
    Intent bindIntent = new Intent(context, Class<Service>);
    boolean bindResult = context.bindService(bindIntent, ServiceConnection, 0);
```

why not using? **getRunningServices()**

```
List<ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo> getRunningServices (int maxNum)
Return a list of the services that are currently running.
```

**Note: this method is only intended for debugging or implementing service management type user interfaces.**

---

**ps. android  documentation is misleading i have opened an issue on google tracker to eliminate any doubts:**

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/68908332

as we can see bind service actually invokes a transaction via ActivityManager binder through Service cache binders - i dint track which service is responsible for binding but as we can see the result for bind is:

```
int res = ActivityManagerNative.getDefault().bindService(...);
return res != 0;
```

transaction is made through binder:

```
ServiceManager.getService("activity");
```

next:

```
  public static IBinder getService(String name) {
    try {
        IBinder service = sCache.get(name);
        if (service != null) {
            return service;
        } else {
            return getIServiceManager().getService(name);
```

this is set in ActivityThread  via:

```
 public final void bindApplication(...) {

        if (services != null) {
            // Setup the service cache in the ServiceManager
            ServiceManager.initServiceCache(services);
        }
```

this is called in ActivityManagerService in method:

```
 private final boolean attachApplicationLocked(IApplicationThread thread,
            int pid) {
    ...
    thread.bindApplication(... , getCommonServicesLocked(),...)
```

then:

```
 private HashMap<String, IBinder> getCommonServicesLocked() {
```

but there is no "activity" only window package and alarm..

so we need get back to  call:

```
 return getIServiceManager().getService(name);

    sServiceManager = ServiceManagerNative.asInterface(BinderInternal.getContextObject());
```

this makes call through:

```
    mRemote.transact(GET_SERVICE_TRANSACTION, data, reply, 0);
```

which leads to :

```
BinderInternal.getContextObject()
```

and this is native method....

```
  /**
     * Return the global "context object" of the system.  This is usually
     * an implementation of IServiceManager, which you can use to find
     * other services.
     */
    public static final native IBinder getContextObject();
```

i don't have time now to dug in c so until i dissect rest call i suspend my answer.

**but best way for check if service is running** is to create bind (if bind is not created service not exist) - and query the service about its state through the bind (using stored internal flag on it state).

### update 23.06.2018

i found those interesting:

```
/**
 * Provide a binder to an already-bound service.  This method is synchronous
 * and will not start the target service if it is not present, so it is safe
 * to call from {@link #onReceive}.
 *
 * For peekService() to return a non null {@link android.os.IBinder} interface
 * the service must have published it before. In other words some component
 * must have called {@link android.content.Context#bindService(Intent, ServiceConnection, int)} on it.
 *
 * @param myContext The Context that had been passed to {@link #onReceive(Context, Intent)}
 * @param service Identifies the already-bound service you wish to use. See
 * {@link android.content.Context#bindService(Intent, ServiceConnection, int)}
 * for more information.
 */
public IBinder peekService(Context myContext, Intent service) {
    IActivityManager am = ActivityManager.getService();
    IBinder binder = null;
    try {
        service.prepareToLeaveProcess(myContext);
        binder = am.peekService(service, service.resolveTypeIfNeeded(
                myContext.getContentResolver()), myContext.getOpPackageName());
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
    }
    return binder;
}
```

in short :)

**"Provide a binder to an already-bound service.  This method is synchronous and will not start the target service if it is not present."**

public IBinder peekService(Intent service, String resolvedType,
                String callingPackage) throws RemoteException;

> *

```
public static IBinder peekService(IBinder remote, Intent service, String resolvedType)
             throws RemoteException {
    Parcel data = Parcel.obtain();
    Parcel reply = Parcel.obtain();
    data.writeInterfaceToken("android.app.IActivityManager");
    service.writeToParcel(data, 0);
    data.writeString(resolvedType);
    remote.transact(android.os.IBinder.FIRST_CALL_TRANSACTION+84, data, reply, 0);
    reply.readException();
    IBinder binder = reply.readStrongBinder();
    reply.recycle();
    data.recycle();
    return binder;
}
```

> *

Comment: bindResult(return value of bindService method) does not come as false if service is not running.

Answer (score 2):

Please use this code.

```
if (isMyServiceRunning(MainActivity.this, xyzService.class)) { // Service class name
    // Service running
} else {
    // Service Stop
}


public static boolean isMyServiceRunning(Activity activity, Class<?> serviceClass) {
        ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        for (ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
            if (serviceClass.getName().equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: getRunningServices is deprecated in android O

Answer (score 1):

There can be several services with the same class name.

I've just created two apps. The package name of the first app is `com.example.mock`. I created a subpackage called `lorem` in the app and a service called `Mock2Service`. So its fully qualified name is `com.example.mock.lorem.Mock2Service`.

Then I created the second app and a service called `Mock2Service`. The package name of the second app is `com.example.mock.lorem`. The fully qualified name of the service is `com.example.mock.lorem.Mock2Service`, too.

Here is my logcat output.

```
03-27 12:02:19.985: D/TAG(32155): Mock-01: com.example.mock.lorem.Mock2Service
03-27 12:02:33.755: D/TAG(32277): Mock-02: com.example.mock.lorem.Mock2Service
```

A better idea is to compare `ComponentName` instances because `equals()` of `ComponentName` compares both package names and class names. And there can't be two apps with the same package name installed on a device.

The equals() method of `ComponentName`.

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    try {
        if (obj != null) {
            ComponentName other = (ComponentName)obj;
            // Note: no null checks, because mPackage and mClass can
            // never be null.
            return mPackage.equals(other.mPackage)
                    && mClass.equals(other.mClass);
        }
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
    }
    return false;
}
```

[ComponentName](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ComponentName.html)

Answer (score 1):

If you have a multi-module application and you want to know that service is running or not from a module that is not depends on the module that contains the service, you can use this function:

```
fun isServiceRunning(context: Context, serviceClassName: String): Boolean {

    val manager = ContextCompat.getSystemService(
        context,
        ActivityManager::class.java
    ) ?: return false

    return manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE).any { serviceInfo ->
        serviceInfo.service.shortClassName.contains(vpnServiceClassName)
    }
}
```

Usage for `MyService` service:

```
isServiceRunning(context, "MyService")
```

> This function may not work correctly if the service class name changes and the calling function does not change accordingly.

Comment: `getRunningServices` is deprecated since Android O (8.1)

Comment: Yes, it is. I do not know any alternative.

Answer (score 1):

Here's good solution I've come up with, but it works only for the Services running in separate processes. This can be achieved by adding an `android:process` attribute in the manifest, e.g.

```
<service
        android:name=".ExampleService"
        android:process="com.example.service"
        ...
```

Now your service will be running in a separate process with the given name. From your app you can call

```
val activityManager = context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE) as ActivityManager
activityManager.runningAppProcesses.any { it.processName == "com.example.service" }
```

Which will return `true` if the service is running and `false` otherwise.

*IMPORTANT:* note that it will show you when your service was started, but when you disable it (meaning, after system unbinds from it) the process can still be alive. So you can simply force it's removal:

```
override fun onUnbind(intent: Intent?): Boolean {
    stopSelf()
    return super.onUnbind(intent)
}

override fun onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy()
    killProcess(Process.myPid())
}
```

Then it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

This applies more towards Intent Service debugging since they spawn a thread, but may work for regular services as well. I found this thread thanks to Binging

In my case, I played around with the debugger and found the thread view. It kind of looks like the bullet point icon in MS Word. Anyways, you don't have to be in debugger mode to use it. Click on the process and click on that button. Any Intent Services will show up while they are running, at least on the emulator.

Answer (score 0):

If the service belongs to another process or APK use the solution based on the ActivityManager.

If you have access to its source, just use the solution based on a static field. But instead using a boolean I would suggest using a Date object. While the service is running, just update its value to 'now' and when it finishes set it to null. From the activity you can check if its null or the date is too old which will mean that it is not running.

You can also send broadcast notification from your service indicating that is running along further info like progress.

Answer (score 0):

My kotlin conversion of the `ActivityManager::getRunningServices` based answers. Put this function in an activity-

```
private fun isMyServiceRunning(serviceClass: Class<out Service>) =
    (getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE) as ActivityManager)
        .getRunningServices(Int.MAX_VALUE)
        ?.map { it.service.className }
        ?.contains(serviceClass.name) ?: false
```

Comment: Its advised that the ActivityManager is only really to be used for Debug purposes.

Answer (score 0):

My solution uses `sendOrderedBroadcast`. It is similar to the ping-pong method using the deprecated `LocalBroadcastManager`.

By using `sendOrderedBroadcast` to ping the service, the following happens:

- If the service is alive:

  1. The system sends the ping action. Since there is one broadcast receiver registered for the ping action, i.e. the service's `pingActionBroadcastReceiver`, the ping action will be sent to it first.
  2. The service's `pingActionBroadcastReceiver` receives the ping action and sets the ping action's `resultCode` to `1`.
  3. Since there are no more broadcast receivers that can process the ping action, the system sends the ping action back to the argument we provided to `sendOrderedBroadcast`'s `resultReceiver: BroadcastReceiver?`, i.e. `pingActionResultBroadcastReceiver`.
  4. `pingActionResultBroadcastReceiver` receives the ping action with its `resultCode` is set to `1`.
- If the service is **NOT** alive:

  1. The system sends the ping action. Since there are no broadcast receivers registered for the ping action, the system sends the ping action back to the argument we provided to `sendOrderedBroadcast`'s `resultReceiver: BroadcastReceiver?`, i.e. `pingActionResultBroadcastReceiver`.
  2. `pingActionResultBroadcastReceiver` receives the ping action with its `resultCode` equal to the argument we provided to `sendOrderedbroadcast`'s `initialCode: Int` which is `0`.

Steps:

1. Setup the pong part: create a `BroadcastReceiver` for receiving the ping action in the `Service` you would like to check.

```kotlin
class SomeService : Service() {
    // instantiate your ping action broadcast receiver
    private val pingActionBroadcastReceiver = PingActionBroadcastReceiver()

    override fun onCreate() {
        // ...

        /*
          register the ping action broadcast receiver

          you may set the `flags` to whatever you want depending
          your use case, e.g. if you want other apps to be able
          to check for your service's presence, set the `flags` to
          `ContextCompat.RECEIVER_EXPORTED` instead
        */
        ContextCompat.registerReceiver(
            /* context = */ this,
            /* receiver = */ pingActionBroadcastReceiver,
            /* filter = */ IntentFilter(PING_ACTION),
            /* flags = */ ContextCompat.RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED,
        )

        // ...
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        // ...

        // don't forget to unregister your broadcast receiver
        unregisterReceiver(pingActionBroadcastReceiver)

        // ...
    }

    private class PingActionBroadcastReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {
        override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
            if (!isOrderedBroadcast) {
                /*
                  we only want broadcasts that were sent using
                  `sendOrderedBroadcast`
                */
                return
            }

            /*
              this is the pong part

              we call `setResult` with `code` equal to `1` because
              we want to tell the broadcaster that the service is alive.

              you may set `data: String?` and `extras: Bundle?` to
              anything you want depending on your use case.
            */
            setResult(
                /* code = */ 1,
                /* data = */ null,
                /* extras = */ null,
            )
            
            /*
              if you're only interested in the result code just set
              `resultCode` to `1` instead of calling `setResult`.
            */
            resultCode = 1
        }
    }

    companion object {
        const val PING_ACTION = "<your ping action>"
    }

    // ...
}
```

2. Setup the ping part. In this example code, we want to check if the service is running every time the user navigates to our activity.

```kotlin
class SomeActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    // instantiate your ping action result broadcast receiver
    private val pingActionResultBroadcastReceiver =
            PingActionResultBroadcastReceiver()

    override fun onStart() {
        // ...

        // this is the ping part
        sendOrderedBroadcast(
            /* intent = */ Intent(SomeService.PING_ACTION),
            /* receiverPermission = */ null,
            /* resultReceiver = */ pingActionResultBroadcastReceiver,
            /* scheduler = */ null,
            /* initialCode = */ 0,
            /* initialData = */ null,
            /* initialExtras = */ null,
        )

        // ...
    }

    private inner class PingActionResultBroadcastReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {
        override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
            if (resultCode == 1) {
                /*
                  do something if the service is alive
 
                  `resultCode` is equal to `1` since it's the
                  integer value we set from the service's ping
                  action broadcast receiver
                */
            } else if (resultCode == 0) {
                /*
                  do something if the service is NOT alive
                 
                  `resultCode` is equal to `0` since it's the
                  `initialCode` integer value we passed to
                  the `sendOrderedBroadcast` call above
                */
            }
        }
    }

    // ...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Since Android 8 (or Oreo), API **getRunningServices is deprecated**.
Of course your can use `@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")` to get rid of the warning.

Here is how to do without getRunninngServices if your service does not need to have more than one instance: use the singleton pattern.

```
public class MyMusicService extends Service {

    private static MyMusicService instance = null;
    
    public static boolean isMyMusicServiceRunning() {
        return instance != null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        // ... do your business
        MyMusicService.instance = this;
    }
}
```

Then you can call the `MyMusicService.isMyMusicServiceRunning` from your activities or elsewhere.

Comment: You haven't set values to the "instance"...

Comment: I edited the code to show where to set the instance.

Answer (score -5):

Take it easy guys... :)

I think the most suitable solution is holding a key-value pair in `SharedPreferences` about if the service is running or not.

Logic is very straight; at any desired position in your service class; put a boolean value which will act as a flag for you about whether the service is running or not. Then read this value whereever you want in your application.

A sample code which I am using in my app is below:

In my Service class (A service for Audio Stream), I execute the following code when the service is up;

```
private void updatePlayerStatus(boolean isRadioPlaying)
{
        SharedPreferences sharedPref = this.getSharedPreferences(getString(R.string.str_shared_file_name), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
        editor.putBoolean(getString(R.string.str_shared_file_radio_status_key), isRadioPlaying);
        editor.commit();
}
```

Then in any activity of my application, I am checking the status of the service with the help of following code;

```
private boolean isRadioRunning() {
        SharedPreferences sharedPref = this.getSharedPreferences(getString(R.string.str_shared_file_name), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        return sharedPref.getBoolean(getString(R.string.str_shared_file_radio_status_key), false);
}
```

No special permissions, no loops... Easy way, clean solution :)

If you need extra information, please refer the [link](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Only that nobody will update the value for you when they kill the service

Comment: when kill the service onDestroy() will triggered and that is possible to update its state

Comment: @JongzPuangput, `onDestroy` isn't always called when the service is killed. For example, I've seen my services killed in low memory situations without `onDestroy` being called.

Comment: @Sam Then what will get called?

Comment: @RuchirBaronia As far as I remember, you simply don't get notified when your stuff is killed. I believe Android is designed to kill apps as needed, and apps should be designed to expect to be killed at any point without notification.

Answer (score -9):

It is possible for you to use this options from the Android Developer options to see if your service is still running in the background.

```
1. Open Settings in your Android device.
2. Find Developer Options.
3. Find Running Services option.
4. Find your app icon.
5. You will then see all the service that belongs to your app running in the background.
```