# How do I ask a Android service whether it's running?

Tags: android, android-service

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [android: check if a service is running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/600207/android-check-if-a-service-is-running)

I have a service with puts up a notification. If the user leaves the App and comes back I want to toggle a button if the service is running.
How do I check whether the service is running?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/600207/android-check-if-a-service-is-running