# Android wifi connection

Tags: wifi, android-wifi

Hie members! ----am Boniface M  - -  a beginner in android[University student]..

My question is am planning to develop an android app/middleware that will act as a grid service .i.e an app for grid computing.. the application needs to be installed in 1....n devices. in the connection, one device must act as a server for all others. communication between the devices is via the wifi under the permission of the server device.which is determined by a certain algorithm[no problem here].

The problem is should i use a database that will keep track of all the services a device is running which are accessible to other devices or is there any way that i can directly keep all this information and then retrieve them as i request them from another app installed in  another device.
and also how i can share files via wifi like blutooth

Thanks....

Answer (score 1):

You're asking many questions in one and I'm actually unsure what you mean overall. Here's a few links that are sure be of some use...

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html This library is good for finding out information about the device you're running on.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Criteria.html - Criteria might be useful, lets you know what location based services you have running

Other than that, if you're looking to see if particular things are running check out this question: [How to check if a service is running on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/600207/android-check-if-a-service-is-running)

If you're looking to keep a central hub of what devices have what available etc. you're going to need a middle man for what you want to do I suspect. If it was me, I'd do HTTP requests to a server, to php scripts I have written which would then read/write from a MySQL database to get information about other devices.

If you want to share files via wifi.. you're going to need an FTP server on the phone. There's an app swiFTP which does this to some degree (phone -> PC) but the concept should be the same. Take a look at it. It's a starting point! http://www.tested.com/news/how-to-transfer-files-wirelessly-to-your-android-phone/53/

Again, I'm unsure EXACTLY what you're looking to do but hopefully all of that is of some help. If it's not leave me a comment and I'll try and assist you further.

hope it helps!

Comment: i have already gone through the developer.android.com documentation for wifi....my choice was also HTTP Request but i felt that this will not a good approach but let me do it this way and will be back to stackoverflow.com for more queries...Thanks.