# Android- create a service flag

Tags: android, listview, service

How would I go about creating a flag so that if a `service` is running, and the user clicks on another `listview` item that it will check to see if a `service` is running, and thus stop it? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use something like -

```
private boolean isMyServiceRunning() {
ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
for (RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
    if ("com.example.MyService".equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
        return true;
    }
}
return false;
}
```

Ref - [How to check if a service is running on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/600207/android-check-if-a-service-is-running)

Comment: Thanks Suchi. I will try this out right now and let you know my results. Thanks for your help

Comment: So in the "com.example.MyService" I put in my package name with the name of the service at the end right?