# How to tell if my unbound service is running?

Tags: android, service

I have read the other threads about [checking if a service is running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/600207/android-check-if-a-service-is-running) but this is not working for me.

My situation is that am creating a background web server service but not binding to it because I want it to continue running after the activity ends.  The service creates a notification so users can see it is running.  The user can stop the service through a button on the Activity.

This is all working fine, except on launch of the activity, I can't determine if the service is already running.  Am using the following:

```
if (isMyServiceRunning() == false)
{
  Intent ws = new Intent(this, WebServerService.class);
  startService(ws);
}
```

And this

```
private boolean isMyServiceRunning() {

    String sClassName;

    ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    for (RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) 
    {
        sClassName = service.service.getClassName();
        DebugMsg("Service: " + sClassName);

        if (sClassName.contains("com.<mydomain>.webservice"))
        {
              return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

I get a list of services running, for both system and 3rd party services.  But my service doesn't show up in the list, even though I know it's running.  If I go into the phone's Settings -> Applications -> Running Services, I can see it running there.

I read in the documentation somewhere that calling startService on a service that is already running should be ignored.  But that isn't the case as I can see in the debugger that both OnCreate and OnStart are being called.

It is important that I do not create a new service each time because the background service may be in the middle of serving a file.  The activity does not need to do any communication with the service - only start it if it isn't running and kill it if the user hits a button.

Any idea on why my service is not showing up in the getRunningServices list?

Comment: btw will getSystemService(..) list at all my local service?! I don't think soo.. :S

Answer (score 4):

Step #1: Add `static boolean isRunning=false` to your service.

Step #2: Set `isRunning` to `true` in `onCreate()` of the service.

Step #3: Set `isRunning` to `false` in `onDestroy()` of the service.

Step #4: Examine `isRunning` to see if the service is running.

> I read in the documentation somewhere that calling startService on a service that is already running should be ignored. But that isn't the case as I can see in the debugger that both OnCreate and OnStart are being called.

I am very confident that `onCreate()` is not called when `startService()` is invoked on a running service. `onStartCommand()` (and, hence, `onStart()` for older services) will be called for every `startService()` call.

> It is important that I do not create a new service each time

Services are natural singletons. There will be precisely 0 or 1 copies of the service in memory. There will never be 2 or more.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, but no luck.  Context on isRunning is lost.  I set it to true in OnCreate and check the variable the second time I call startService, and it is still false.  onCreate and onStart are always being called. I even created separate static counters incremented for every onCreate, onStart and onDestroy.  They are always zero after startService is called.  Interesting though that onDestroy is never being called.

Comment: @Gregg Reno: Then something is seriously messed up with your app. Make sure you don't have `android:process` attributes in your manifest or something that would cause you to have separate processes.

Comment: Does it matter that I am also using an IntentService to communicate to another server?
<service android:name=".HTTPIntentService"></service>
<service android:name="com.mydomain.webservice.WebServerService" android:enabled="true"  />

Comment: Or as an alternative, can I see if there is an active notification (I create it from my service with FLAG_NO_CLEAR)?  Seems I can only Notify or Cancel with NotificationManager.

Comment: @Gregg Reno: "can I see if there is an active notification" -- not really.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, my service is now showing up in the list of services.  I'm now thinking that maybe the service name wasn't registered until after restarting the phone, because I didn't make any changes but everything is working now after restarting.

Comment: Uffff.. that is super messy.. How would u be sure that this would not happen when users are running your app? ;(