# How do we know if a service has stopped in a bound and unbound service?

Tags: android, service, android-activity

How do we know if a service has stopped in a bound and unbound service?

I want to check constantly if a service has stopped and what is its state/status?

Thanks
Sneha

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/600207/android-check-if-a-service-is-running/4976378#4976378

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
public boolean isServiceRunning(String serviceName) { 
        ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE); 
        List<RunningServiceInfo> infos = manager.getRunningServices(30); 
        for (RunningServiceInfo info : infos) { 
            if (info.service.getClassName().equals(serviceName)) { 
                return true; 
            } 
        } 
        return false; 
    }
```