# Creating start stop service button

Tags: android, android-service

I want to create a single button which serves both functions of Starting and Stopping a service.

Also I want to make sure that even if user quits the application and again comes back then according to whether service is running or not, I want to show appropriate Text on Button.

So in short, With what thing I can get to know if service is running or not ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [android: check if a service is running](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/600207/android-check-if-a-service-is-running)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check if service is running or not with below code. Rest of the question is logic based once you find the service is running or not.

```
private boolean isMyServiceRunning() {
    ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    for (RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
        if ("com.example.MyService".equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

I refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5921190/582571) just check it