# Conflict accessing sqlite database android, from Service and onClick

Tags: android, multithreading, sqlite, service

In my app android, I can access to my sqlite database from:

1) Service android, every 60 seconds.

2) After pressure of button (onclik)

If I press the button while my service is accessing the database an error occurs.

So I insert in the onclickListener, before access to database, a call to stopService()

but the conflict remains, because, even if I call stopService() before access to database, the service is stopped after this!

I tried, using :

```
private boolean isMyServiceRunning() {
    ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager)  getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    for (RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
        if ("com.example.MyService".equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
           return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
 }
```

suggested in [How to check if a service is running on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/600207/android-check-if-a-service-is-running)

I tried to call this method, before access to database, in this manner:

```
    while(isMyServiceRunning())
    {
        // do nothing
    }

    // *** access to my database ***
```

What can I do in order to be sure that my service is stopped before accessing to database?

The error is:

```
10-30 21:05:43.360: E/SQLiteDatabase(13960): Failed to open the database. closing it.
10-30 21:05:43.360: E/SQLiteDatabase(13960):        android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabaseLockedException: database is locked
10-30 21:05:43.360: E/SQLiteDatabase(13960):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.native_setLocale(Native Method)
10-30 21:05:43.360: E/SQLiteDatabase(13960):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.setLocale(SQLiteDatabase.java:2115)
10-30 21:05:43.360: E/SQLiteDatabase(13960):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:984)
10-30 21:05:43.360: E/SQLiteDatabase(13960):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:956)
10-30 21:05:43.360: E/SQLiteDatabase(13960):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:1021)
10-30 21:05:43.360: E/SQLiteDatabase(13960):    at android.app.ContextImpl.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextImpl.java:753)
10-30 21:05:43.360: E/SQLiteDatabase(13960):    at android.content.ContextWrapper.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextWrapper.java:221)
10-30 21:05:43.360: E/SQLiteDatabase(13960):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:149)
10-30 21:05:43.360: E/SQLiteDatabase(13960):    at host.database.DB_DatabaseManager.open(DB_DatabaseManager.java:134)
```

Comment: Can you post what kind of conflict you are facing ?

Do you close database in your service ?

Comment: Yes, @Jagdeep, I close database in service. I edit my question, adding the error

Answer (score 1):

You can override the `onDestroy()` event for the service and try to access the database on it:

```java
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    // *** access to my database ***
    super.onDestroy();
}
```