# Monitor services in android

Tags: java, android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [android: check if a service is running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/600207/android-check-if-a-service-is-running)

I have one services to perform my action, it will run on background indefinite time. I want to monitor the service whether its is running or not. So, I want to create another service to monitor first one.

Is There any other action interfilter to broadcast, service running or not?

Comment: "it will run on background indefinite time" -- why? Users generally do not like this, which is why users will get rid of your services via task killers, "Force Stop" in Settings, etc.

Comment: @CommonsWare If the user 'force stop' the services, if it is possible to get the notification?

Comment: Absolutely not. By force-stopping your app, the user is indicating that the user does not want your app to run anymore, because your app is ill-behaved. Your process is immediately terminated, and you are not notified of this fact. So, I ask again: why do you have a service that "will run on background indefinite time"?

Comment: @CommonsWare I want to block camera process in one service and want to watch another service whether it is running or not. If not i want to re-start the service again

Comment: "I want to block camera process in one service" -- talented programmers use the device admin APIs to control access to the camera, rather than playing childish script-kiddie games with processes and everlasting services.

Comment: Of course, Admin APIs for disabling camera will work on Android ICS. For the lower version of android, am doing these workaround.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`getRunningServices(int max)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#getRunningServices%28int%29) of `ActivityManager`

ActivityManager actManager = // get the activity manager

```
int max = ??;

List<ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo> runningServices = actManager.getRunningServices(max);

for(ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo runningService : runningServices)
{

   boolean started = runningService.started;
}
```

**Note:** this method is only intended for debugging or implementing service management type user interfaces.

Comment: I want to know, is there any notification available when service is stopped?..or else i want to check this method in services in indfinite time?