# Android SplashActivity show only once

Tags: android, splash-screen

I have got a splash screen activity which launches the main activity, and from the main activity I start a service, when I close the application, the service is still running, but when I relaunch it, it shows the splash screen again.

How can I make it appear only once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either use the solution above, or at least the part where I check if the application started the first time. But I guess you solved it already...

I prefer adding a `Splash Screen Layout` on top of my `main_activity.xml`. I detect the first start of the application by extending Application. If it´s the first start, I show my Splash-Screen while the UI is build in the background... (Use background threads if the ProgressBar lags!)

```
//Extend Application to save the value. You could also use getter/setter for this instead of Shared Preferences...
public class YourApplication extends Application {

    public static final String YOUR_APP_STARTUP = "APP_FIRST_START";

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        //set SharedPreference value to true
        SharedPreferences mPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mPreferences.edit();
        editor.putBoolean(YOUR_APP_STARTUP, true);
        editor.apply();     
        ...    
     }
```

Check for your first start in your `MainActivity`

```
public class YourMainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //hide actionbar and other menu which could overlay the splash screen
    getActionBar().hide();

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Boolean firstStart = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext()).getBoolean(TVApplication.YOUR_APP_STARTUP, true);

    if (firstStart) {
        //First app start, show splash screen an hide it after 5000ms
        final RelativeLayout mSplashScreen = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.splash_screen);
        mSplashScreen.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mSplashScreen.setAlpha(1.0f);
        final FrameLayout mFrame = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.frame_container);
        mFrame.setAlpha(0.0f);

        Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Animation fadeOutAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),
                        R.anim.fade_out_animation);
                fadeOutAnimation.setDuration(500);
                fadeOutAnimation.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                        mFrame.setAlpha(1.0f);
                        getActionBar().show();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                        mSplashScreen.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

                    }
                });
                mSplashScreen.startAnimation(fadeOutAnimation);
            }
        }, 5000); //<-- time of Splash Screen shown

    } else {
        ((RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.splash_screen)).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        getActionBar().show();
    }
```

Insert the SplashScreen at top in your main.xml. I prefer `RelativeLayout` for that. In the example, SplashScreen is placed on to of a layout with the `Navitgation Drawer`, which we really love, don`t we?

```
//main_activity.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <!-- The main content view -->

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/frame_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <!-- The navigation drawer list -->

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/slider_list"
            android:layout_width="240dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:background="@color/tvtv_background"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:divider="@drawable/nav_bar_divider"
            android:dividerHeight="1dp"
            android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent" />
    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/splash_screen"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@color/tvtv_white"
        android:visibility="visible" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/splash_screen_logo"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:paddingLeft="50dp"
            android:paddingRight="50dp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/splash_screen_text"
            style="@style/TVTextBlueContent"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/splash_screen_logo"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="Awesome splash shiat" />

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/splash_screen_loader"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/splash_screen_text"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:indeterminate="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

in your splash activity, you can check, whether your service is already running(for details see [How to check if a service is running on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/600207/android-check-if-a-service-is-running)). if service is running, you can start main activity and finish splash activity immediately

Comment: but if I'll start the intent the splash will show, then just automatically go to the other