# Stop already started service on application startup

Tags: java, android, service, crash

I have an network app which uses a service to connect to other peers. When you close the application using *"Recent apps"* it will just close the process and not the `service` which is actually not bad for I want to be in this way. But it makes a little trouble next time user opens the app. It crashes so user has to again close the up using *"Recent Apps"* and then try to use the app again. The problem is definitely the running service because if I stop the service before I run it next time. It works just fine !

Actually it is strange for me because I don't start another `service` at the startup. I start it when user taps on a button. Anyway If it is possible the best way is to being able to use the running `service`, else, I just want to stop the service on start of my application.

i am new to android and I'm stuck at this point :(

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

A service skeleton:

```
public class MyService extends Service {
public static final String TAG = "MyServiceTag";
...
}
```

This is part of the starting activity:

processStartService(MyService.TAG);

```
 private void processStartService(final String tag) {
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyService.class);
intent.addCategory(tag);
startService(intent);
}
```

This is part of the stopping activity:

```
processStopService(MyService.TAG);

private void processStopService(final String tag) {
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyService.class);
intent.addCategory(tag);
stopService(intent);
}
```

Comment: This approach will lead to stopping service every time user leaves the app. I want to stop it when the app is closing. I think if I check inside the service if the application process is not running, then I can stop the service and that makes sense. What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

Use one `static` object which indicate whether service is running or not.

otherwise second option I found [How to check if a service is running on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/600207/android-check-if-a-service-is-running/3780768#3780768),

```
if(startService(someIntent) != null) { 
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), 'Service is already running',Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}else {
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), 'There is no service running, starting service..', Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: I did something similar and it is better than nothing but first time the user enters the app, it crashes so he should select it in recent apps and it will work while if I dont do that. User has to close the app and then run it again. So I achieved something, but it's not enough! it should work every time app starts !