# Test if a service is running from the activity

Tags: android, android-service, android-testing

is there a way, using the android testing framework, to check if a service in particular has been started? Thanks.

Comment: I am not very sure because I have not used a test framework for Android but I found this article very helpful since it gives you an idea of how services work and how to check them: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidServices/article.html

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16012142/how-to-check-if-service-is-running-or-not