# Android Button ImageResource changing

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-service, android-button, android-resources

I have button Play/Stop , One button which changes his resource by the playing or not,But when I go to other fragment(Activity) and return to fragment with Play/Stop button, music is playing but resource is default.

If i press button , it stopService and that is OK,only problem is ImageResource change.

My code :

```
int button_status = 1;
.... other code ...

public void onClick(View v) {
if (button_status == 1){

    button_status = 0;
    buttonPlayStop.setImageResource(R.drawable.pause);

    getActivity().startService(new Intent(getActivity(), Service.class));       

    }else{

    button_status = 1;
    buttonPlayStop.setImageResource(R.drawable.play);

    getActivity().stopService(new Intent(getActivity(), Service.class));

    }
}
```

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the status of your `Service` in Activity's `onResume`. Depending on status of `Service` (running or not) you can set your button's resource.

The easiest way to keep track of `Service` status - is introduce some static field which will represent status

Slightly better way for checking if your activity is running or not is using following snippet (stolen from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5921190/1277362)):

```
private boolean isMyServiceRunning() {
    ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager)getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    for (RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
        if (MyService.class.getName().equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```