# Check if service is running on Android?

Tags: android, android-service

l want to check if a service is running
l wrote this code

```
public class startServiceOrNo {
public static void startServiceIfItsNotRuning(Class<?> class1, Context context) {
    ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    for (RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
        if (class1.getName().equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
            Lg.d("servisstart SERVICE ALREADY START" + class1.getName());
            return;
        }
    }
    Lg.d("servisstart SSERVICE NEW SERVIS " + class1.getName());
    context.startService(new Intent(context, class1));
}
```

and use it 
 startServiceOrNo.startServiceIfItsNotRuning(OfflineChopsMonitor.class,this)

if l check service from one class its work, but if l check same service from different class, its check don't work

Comment: what do you want ? do you want to check service is runnning or not ??

Comment: Please check this one
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/600207/android-check-if-a-service-is-running

Answer (score 36):

1.) In Activity class:

```
private boolean isMyServiceRunning(Class<?> serviceClass) {
    ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    for (RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
        if (serviceClass.getName().equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

2.) In Non-Activity class (BroadcastReceiver):

```
private boolean isMyServiceRunning(Class<?> serviceClass,Context context) {
        ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager)context. getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        for (RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
            if (serviceClass.getName().equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
                Log.i("Service already","running");
                return true;
            }
        }
        Log.i("Service not","running");
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Pay attention that getRunningServices is deprecated.

Comment: Thanks for dividing in activity and in non-activity. It maid my work easier.

Answer (score 34):

Why don't you let the Service itself figure that out?

```
public class MyService extends Service
{
    private boolean mRunning;

    @Override
    public void onCreate()
    {
        super.onCreate();
        mRunning = false;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
    {
        if (!mRunning) {
            mRunning = true;
            // do something
        }
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }
}
```

Comment: But how do you get access to your service object from your intent?

Comment: How would you use this from other Activities/Fragments to check whether the Service is running?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky you wouldn't

Comment: Is it not necessary to use a static variable?

Comment: Good solution, also relevant for the scenario when the service suddenly crashes (`onDestroy` not being called), so explicitly changing the value back to `false` inside `onDestroy` method is optional.

Comment: but it is already starting the same service, right ? but you are not doing anything if it is already running. but you start one again anyway, right ?

Comment: useless answer. what about when service dies?

Comment: Upvote. Remember the old school fact, the service which has already been started won't call the oncreate when the startservice is called the next time, therefore, the comment // do something is the safe place here.

Comment: one solution which I found at SO, exclude this deprecated one `getRunningServices` everywhere...

Comment: Using a static field in this case is like drinking using a fork, it will NOT catch all the cases, and it will miss a lot of possibilities

Answer (score 10):

I use following from inside an activity:

```
private boolean isMyServiceRunning(Class<?> serviceClass) {
  ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
  for (RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
    if (serviceClass.getName().equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
        return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

Comment: ActivityManager. getRunningServices is deprecated

Answer (score 2):

You can use this method in Kotlin

```
fun Activity.isServiceRunning(serviceClassName: String): Boolean {
    val manager = getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE) as ActivityManager
    return manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE).any { it.service.className == serviceClassName }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

check if the service is running or not
if my case: `OpenVPNService.class` is my service class

```
if (isMyServiceRunning(OpenVPNService.class)) {
                success_txt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                success_txt.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }





 private boolean isMyServiceRunning(Class<?> serviceClass) {
        ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        for (ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
            if (serviceClass.getName().equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```