# Android: how do check if service is running?

Tags: android, service

Is there any simple way of determining whether or not a certain service is active? I do this

```
    boolean serviceWorking = false;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
       serviceWorking = true;
    }
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
       serviceWorking = false;
       stopSelf(startId);
}
```

but it is not working.

Comment: post the full code

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7399029/ and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/600207/ and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17588910/

Answer (score 7):

Information about running services is provided by the Android operating system through ActivityManager#getRunningServices.
All the approaches using onDestroy or onSometing events or Binders or static variables will not work reliably because as a developer you never know, when Android decides to kill your process or which of the mentioned callbacks are called or not.

U can write a method like this in activity

```
private boolean isMyServiceRunning(Class<?> serviceClass) {
    ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    for (RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
        if (serviceClass.getName().equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

call it using:

```
isMyServiceRunning(MyService.class)
```

Comment: This solution does not work anymore in Android O since getRunningServices has been deprecated. It will now return only the callers own service name.

Comment: the `getRunningServices` is now deprecated and is not advisable to use it

Answer (score 1):

I refer to the following: [Check if service is running on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17588910/check-if-service-is-running-on-android)

```
public class MyService extends Service
{
    private boolean mRunning;

    @Override
    public void onCreate()
    {
        super.onCreate();
        mRunning = false;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
    {
        if (!mRunning) {
            mRunning = true;
            // do something
    }
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }
}
```

Comment: It will be better if you comment link instead of post