# Location is fetching when the app is killed and in background using FusedLocationProviderClient with pending Intent but in Irregular times

Tags: android, location, android-pendingintent, android-fusedlocation, fusedlocationproviderclient

I am using FusedLocationProviderClient with pending intent. I am getting the location when the app is active. But while the app goes into background or app is killed, I am getting the location in irregular intervals say 2mins, 3 mins, 10 mins sometimes. Need help with this?

Note : Also I am targeting Oreo.

[my code](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1_nqpALWsoWICwfRf6fpHbb9S2eBXrELp?usp=sharing)

Comment: This happens because of new battery saving policies. Check the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get location data while your app is in the background on Oreo or higher, you should run a foreground service (or something similar):

https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-location/tree/master/LocationUpdatesForegroundService

With Oreo, Google started limiting what apps can do in the background:

https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background

Comment: Thanks @Gavin Wright but then, I don't want notifications as well. And my minimum sdk version is 15. Please suggest something.

Comment: This could possibly be done with JobScheduler, but you may run into problems because getting location every couple minutes in the background uses a lot of battery. That's why the notification is there, to inform the user about something that's draining lots of battery. Anyways, give it a try I guess: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47224219/how-to-run-a-jobscheduler-or-a-service-every-minute-wihout-stopping

Comment: JobScheduler is for api level greater than 21. I suppose I have to use Firebase Job Dispatcher then.