# android: check if a service is running don't work

Tags: android, service

I try to stop get my service state and stop it if is running. 
Even i use [How to check if a service is running on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/600207/android-check-if-a-service-is-running)

But after stop my the service i remak that it alway run.
Here is my code:

```
public class Sauvegarde_Mail extends Activity{

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.sauvauto_layout_boitemail);
    final Button byActiver = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btactiver);
    Button byDesactiver = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btdesactiver);

    byActiver.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
                BoitedialogMailEdit();
            }
    });

    byDesactiver.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
                if(isMyServiceRunning()==true){
                stopService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyServiceSauvAutoMail.class));}
                byActiver.setEnabled(true);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Processus arreté",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }               
    });
}

private Boolean isMyServiceRunning() {
    ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    for (RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
        if (MyServiceSauvAutoMail.class.getName().equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
            Log.e("i","Bjr");
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

public void BoitedialogMailEdit(){
    AlertDialog.Builder Builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
     LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
     View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_layout3, (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.layout_root));
     final EditText adrmail = (EditText) layout.findViewById(R.id.adrmail);
     Builder.setView(layout);

    Builder.setPositiveButton("VALIDER",
        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            mail = adrmail.getText().toString();
            final Button byActiver = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btactiver);
            Intent intent2 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyServiceSauvAutoMail.class);
            startService(intent2);
            dialog.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Processus démarré.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            byActiver.setEnabled(false);
            }
        });
    AlertDialog dialog = Builder.create();
    dialog.show();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to check whether your `Service` is running or not, simply call `stopService()` on it. It will return `true` if there was such a `Service` running, `false` otherwise. From the [reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#stopService%28android.content.Intent%29):

> Returns: If there is a service matching the given Intent that is
>   already running, then it is stopped and true is returned; else false
>   is returned.

Analogously, `startService()` won't start several `Services` if called several times.

> Returns: If the service is being started or is already running, the ComponentName of the actual service that was started is returned; else if the service does not exist null is returned.

Comment: In my way phicially the service stop in my device service manager. But i remark that it still run. Because the service send mail automatically

Comment: Then something is not working as expected. Check the result values (`boolean`s) and see whether it's the expected value or not.