# Downloading data using IntentService - Lifecycle changes

Tags: android, android-service

**Tl;dr** How to know when an `IntentService` has finished downloading upon returning to the `Activity` which listens to its result using a `BroadcastReceiver`?

---

I'm moving to implementing data downloading to `IntentService`s, and notifying when the task has finished using `BroadcastReceiver`s.

I generally start the service in my `Activity`:

```
IntentFilter intentFilter = DownloadDataService.startDownloadData(this);
getLocalBroadcastManager().registerReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver, intentFilter);
```

The part that starts the `Service`:

```
/**
 * Starts the service and returns an IntentFilter to subscribe a BroadcastReceiver on. 
 * When the task has finished, a broadcast for returned IntentFilter is sent,
 * containing downloaded data.
 */
public static IntentFilter startDownloadData(final Context context) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, DownloadDataService.class);
    intent.setAction(ACTION_DOWNLOAD_DATA);
    context.startService(intent);

    return new IntentFilter(ACTION_DOWNLOAD_DATA);
}
```

And of course, `onHandleIntent(Intent)` (simplified):

```
@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(final Intent intent){
    Data data = downloadData();
    Intent intent = new Intent(ACTION_DOWNLOAD_DATA);
    intent.putExtra(DATA, data);
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent);
}
```

This all works well, and I can keep states in my `Activity` to know for example after an orientation change whether I was waiting for a download data result:

```
@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    if (mState == State.DOWNLOADING) {
        Log.v(TAG, "Registering receiver for existing download data");
        IntentFilter intentFilter = DownloadDataService.getIntentFilter();
        getLocalBroadcastManager().registerReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver, intentFilter);
    }
}
```

Great, now I can also handle orientation changes. Only one problem left:

- `Activity` starts the `DownloadDataService`
- User moves away from the `Activity`
- `DownloadDataService` broadcasts its done message (which is not received by the `Activity` due to `unregisterReceiver` in `onStop()`)
- User moves back into the `Activity`
- `Activity` still thinks it's waiting for the `DownloadDataService`, and does nothing.

How can I compensate for this?

---

Note that I do not have any persistence like databases for storing the downloaded data. The `Activity` retrieves the data from the broadcasted `Intent`.

Note #2: There is [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5921190/675383) to the question of how to know whether a `Service` is running. Although this might work, it is explicitly stated that that method is for *debugging or implementing service management type user interfaces*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't really convinced by using SharedPreferences, static variables and other 'hacky' solutions.

I did find however that you can supply a `ResultReceiver` - which is parcelable - which you can use to notify your task is finished. It receives a `Handler` to specify the thread the result is handled on.

The advantage of this, is that you can save the `ResultReceiver` during `onSaveInstanceState`. Using some clever tricks you can certainly make this work. I have created an experimental library which facilitates this tactic: https://github.com/nhaarman/Ergo

Answer (score 1):

use sendStickyBroadcast to send a sticky broadcast. This broadcast is held by the system.

Comment: I was just about to suggest that in a comment when you posted your answer.

Comment: Ah, yes. But this doesn't work with `LocalBroadcastManager`, right?

Comment: Plus, sticky broadcasts are discouraged [as well](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/8341SaXhvmY).

Comment: @NiekHaarman : I suppose it depends on if the data is sensitive. If it's not then it wouldn't bother me to use a sticky broadcast with a standard BroadcastReceiver. If the data is sensitive then I'm not sure you have many other choices. The only way I can think of is to  maintain a download state in SharedPreferences indicating the Service is downloading or not (perhaps with a last download time) and to persist the data somewhere. Used in combination with a BroadcastReceiver you'd either get the data in real-time or later.

Comment: Or maybe register the broadcast reciever in an application derived class. Or you could let the dowload service register a flag in the shared preferences and check that when you resume the Activity