# Downloading data and updating UI

Tags: android, android-service

There are couple of things that are bugging me in the process of downloading data and notifying the UI in Android. I'm using (`Intent`)`Service`s to download the data, which works good enough.

I'm not sure how to deal with notifying the UI that data has been retrieved though. After some research and discussion in [Downloading data using IntentService - Lifecycle Changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23363027/downloading-data-using-intentservice-lifecycle-changes), and [Which is the best way to communicate between service and activity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23597423/which-is-the-best-way-to-communicate-between-service-and-activity/23597806?noredirect=1#comment36246122_23597806), I'm arriving at a point where I'm not sure which method to use anymore.

The alternatives I'm looking at are:

1. **Service + LocalBroadcasts + Databases**

   - An `Activity` would start the `Service`
   - The `Service` would download the data into a database
   - The `Service` would send out the `Broadcast` with a 'done' notification
   - The `Activity` would pick up this `Broadcast` and retrieve the data from the database using an `AsyncTask`
   - The `Activity` would retrieve the data from the database using an `AsyncTask` every time it is shown to the user (`onResume`, for cases it has missed the broadcast due to the user navigating away).
2. **Service + ResultReceivers + Databases**

   - An `Activity` would start the `Service`
   - The `Service` would download the data into a database
   - The `Service` would notify the `ResultReceiver` that it's done
   - The `Activity` would retrieve the data from the database using an `AsyncTask`
   - Instead of retrieving the data every time, the `ResultReceiver` is reused across lifecycle changes, and notifications are *not* lost.
3. **Service + ResultReceivers + Bundle**

   - An `Activity` would start the `Service`
   - The `Service` would download the data (optionally into a database)
   - The `Service` would notify the `ResultReceiver` that it's done, and supplies the data in a `Bundle`.
   - The `Activity` would retrieve the data from the `Bundle` (No `AsyncTask` needed).
   - Instead of retrieving the data every time, the `ResultReceiver` is reused across lifecycle changes, and notifications are *not* lost.

Options **1** and **2** require the user waiting for the database read/write operations. Option **3** is therefore quicker, but I've seen many sources recommend *not* using `Broadcast`s or `ResultReceiver`s to transfer data (I'm not sure exactly why though).

For now, I am sticking with option **3**, but I'm not sure if this is actually a proper approach, and if I'm missing something.

Can someone shed some light on this?

---

*While some people (possibly righteously) vote this question to be opinion based, I am looking for pitfalls I am possibly overlooking. Furthermore, I'm looking for the answer as to* why *using `ResultReceiver`s or `Broadcast`s for sending result data is recommended against.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Carefully using some sort of `DataManager` singleton instance, backed up by a database seems to be a robust solution. Using `ResultReceiver`s, the UI gets notified and pulls the data from the `DataManager`.

I have also found out that using `ResultReceiver`s and `Broadcast`s to send data has a negative impact on performance, because the objects need to be serialized. This is a costly operation, and GC might kick in because of it.