# How can I stop my old service?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service, android-intentservice

I want to start service when I exit from my app.

code is :

```
Intent i_service   = new Intent(MainActivity.this,check.class);
startService(i_service);
```

And when I re-open my app , I want to stop my service which I started when I exit from my app.

code is:

```
 Intent i_service   = new Intent(MainActivity.this,check.class);
 stopService(i_service);
```

This is the right way to do it ?

How can stop my old service?

thanks in advance

Comment: Yes You are doing in a correct way..

Comment: if my service already  is stopped , does it caused an error

Comment: NO it wont cause any error..it will check and if it is running then it will stop..

Comment: Or you can the service is running or not using  and stop if it is running http://stackoverflow.com/questions/600207/how-to-check-if-a-service-is-running-in-android

Comment: in service do code like whenever work complete services stop automatically then no need to check service is working or not; if you start service again then its automatically do new work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Check Your service is run or not and then stop ur service on oncreate() of ur activity as below,



  ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    for (RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
        if (check.getName().equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
           Intent i_service   = new Intent(MainActivity.this,check.class);
 stopService(i_service); 
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are doing it in the correct way. Just that when the Application is started again, you need to first check whether it is running or not, and then stop it.

The answer with code described by "MSS" above explains it well!