# Call onDestroy() of Service

Tags: android, android-service

I want to call

> onDestroy()

method of Service in android.

I already searched a lot on internet and many answers are like if

**service force stop or somehow its onDestroy() will never call.**

But I really need to know when service is stop.

**My project is about music player.**

So it uses service and there is an ongoing notification.
I need to find out when the service stop? and need to stop the music and remove the notification.

But it never shows any log of `onDestroy()`.
Can anyone help me what is the alternative for it? if not `onDestroy()` then which method and how?

Edit:

I don't want to call `onDestroy()` explicitly. I want to remove notification when I remove my app from the device menu of running applications. Because when I stop my application, `onDestroy()` don't call and my notification remains in the status bar.

I have started my service with this code.

```java
Intent playin = new Intent(this, MusicService.class);
startService(playin);
```

Comment: Do you mean that you want to log when the application crashes?

Comment: Do you want to call the onDestroy() of the service or do you want to know when the service crashes so you can get rid of you notification.

Comment: How are you starting your service? is it bounded server or unbounded?

Answer (score 9):

**From within the *Service* class, call:**

`stopSelf();`

**From within another class, like your *MainActivity* for example:**

`Intent i = new Intent(this, ServiceName.class);
stopService(i);`

Both of these will stop your service. Make sure you are returning `START_NOT_STICKY` so that the service doesn't start back up again.

Comment: Will `stopSelf()` invoke `onDestroy()`?

Answer (score 2):

> I want to call `onDestroy()` method of `Service` in android.

- Do not call this method directly

> **public void onDestroy ()**
>
> Called by the system to notify a Service that it is no longer used and
>   is being removed. The service should clean up any resources it holds
>   (threads, registered receivers, etc) at this point. Upon return, there
>   will be no more calls in to this Service object and it is effectively
>   dead. Do not call this method directly.

However you can check if the service is running or not.

> I need to find out when service stop? and need to stop music and
>   remove notification.

Use the following way -

```
private boolean isMyServiceRunning(Class<?> serviceClass) {
    ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    for (RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
        if (serviceClass.getName().equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Then call it using  - `isMyServiceRunning(MyService.class)`.

*Reference:*

1) [Service onDestroy()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#onDestroy()).

2) [how-to-check-if-a-service-is-running-in-android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/600207/how-to-check-if-a-service-is-running-in-android).

Comment: So should `stopSelf()` be called instead of `onDestroy()`?

Answer (score 2):

When you want to stop your service then simply fire an intent to stop the service as shown below.

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setClass(getApplicationContext(), YourService.class);
stopService(intent);
```

This is to stop service forcefully.When you stop service in this manner it's guaranteed that onDestroy method is called by android framework.

Hope this helps to solve you issue.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [Foreground service](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/foreground-services). In your case, I think it  would be the best choice.

Foreground services show a status bar notification, so that users are actively aware that your app is performing a task in the foreground and is consuming system resources. The notification cannot be dismissed unless the service is either stopped or removed from the foreground.

To work with foreground service you first need to declare permission `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE"/>` in your manifest. It is a normal permission so doesn't requires user action.

then, you can start the service for you Activity or other component using `applicationContext.startForgroundService(intent)`. this is to tell the system that this will be a foreground service.

You need to start the foreground service from within your service(usually in `onStartCommand()`) using `startForeground(int, Notification)` and stop the service foreground service using `stopForeground(boolean)`(it takes a boolean asking whether you want to remove the notification or not)

after starting foreground service, if you close your app or the service stops itself, the notification will be remove too.

**Note**: when you manually want to stop the service, you should call `stopSelf()` or `stopService()` as calling `stopForeground()` is not enough, it merely remove the notification from the status bar.