# Service does not stop even after onDestroy method is called in Android

Tags: android, android-studio, android-service

I'm still new to android. I call the onDestroy method using stopService. The onDestroy method is called as I can see the toast message. But the infinite for loop used to send location updates keeps running. 
Is there something I need to change?

```
public class myservice extends IntentService {
    LocationManager locationManager ;
    public myservice() {
        super(myservice.class.getName());
    }
    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        String numb=intent.getStringExtra("num");
        for (;;) {
            send(numb);
        }
    }

    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    public void send(String numb) {
        locationManager = (LocationManager)this
                .getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission( this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION ) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ) {}
        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
        Geocoder geocoder;
        geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
        try {
            Thread.sleep(3000);
            List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude(), 1);
            Toast toast1 = Toast.makeText(this, "message sent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast1.setText(numb.toString());
            toast1.show();
            SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
            smsManager.sendTextMessage(numb, null, "current postition is" + addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0) + "," + addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(1) + "," + addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(2), null, null);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SMS sent.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SMS faild, please try again.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "DESTROY2", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        super.stopSelf();
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

Comment: if you wanna control the service then don't extent it from intent service instead of extend it from service then when you call stop service , you will be able to stop it.

Comment: you can call Intent i = new Intent(this, ServiceName.class);
stopService(i);  to stope service

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24830716/3790150

Comment: Did you stop your infinite loop somehow?

Comment: @TinTran that was the issue. I gave a stop condition for the loop and it worked. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

You don't call `onDestroy()` yourself.  Never call lifecycle methods on your own.  Android will call them when the service is stopped.

Subclassing IntentService isn't really the best thing to do to manage ongoing work.  It would be better for you to manage a thread on your own and manage the start and stop commands that are delivered to that service.  It's not exactly easy work.

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html