# How do i predefine a flag in sharedPreferences?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I want to define a flag in android sharedPreferences to check whether a service is running or not, but it can't be at runtime, so is it possible to do it somehow in xml? also, is there anyway that i can check whether a service is running or not?

Answer (score 0):

I don't get why you can't define a flag for SharedPreferences, but if you want to check if service running you can [create global variable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/608600/341998) and check it:

```
public class MyService extends Service {
        public static boolean sIsRunning;


        @Override
        public void onCreate() {
            super.onCreate();
            sIsRunning = true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroy() {
            super.onDestroy();
            sIsRunning = false;
        }
    }
```

Or [check running services](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5921190/341998) with ActivityManager:

```
private boolean isMyServiceRunning(Class<?> serviceClass) {
    ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    for (RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
        if (serviceClass.getName().equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```