# Stop the service when the App is closed and not when the user changes the activity

Tags: android

I have a trackingService `locationManager`  component which processes in the background and it is launched from the `MainActivity` activity. At the same time, I have another component to retrieve this data from the server and displaying it in the `Map` activity. The user can access data in the server from the MainActivity, when he clicks a buton in it. Thereupon, the data is being retrieved from the server and the user redirects to the `Map` activity. Everything it works for me so far.

I am trying to remove the `locationManager` in two cases:

- When the user click the checkbox in the menu of  MainActivity.
- or when he closes the app (Not when the user changes the activity).

With this code snippet:

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    unregisterReceiver(wifi_receiver);
    System.out.println("ABC TrackingService onDestroy() was invoked.");
    // commeted 13.08.15

    if(lm != null){
        lm.removeUpdates(this);
        System.out.println("ABC lm locationManager is not equal null.");
    }else{
        System.out.println("ABC lm locationManager is null.");

    }       
}
```

I have tried it with the code below so when I click the button in the MainActivity for the first time, the user is being redirected to the `Map` activity and the service works (without calling the `onDestroy()` in the `TrackingService` class) but when I go back from the Map activity to the MainActivity(Service still works) and then clicks the button to go again to the `Map` activity, at this point, the `onDestroy()` in the `TrackingService` class is being called and the service stops

With this code snippet:

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    unregisterReceiver(wifi_receiver);
    System.out.println("ABC TrackingService onDestroy() was invoked.");
    lm.removeUpdates(this);

}
```

I am getting this error below:
**Error:**

```
08-29 12:46:06.624: E/AndroidRuntime(6332): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-29 12:46:06.624: E/AndroidRuntime(6332): Process: com.bustracker, PID: 6332
08-29 12:46:06.624: E/AndroidRuntime(6332): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to stop service com.bustracker.TrackingService@1e57ec95: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.location.LocationManager.removeUpdates(android.location.LocationListener)' on a null object reference
08-29 12:46:06.624: E/AndroidRuntime(6332):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStopService(ActivityThread.java:3356)
08-29 12:46:06.624: E/AndroidRuntime(6332):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:177)
08-29 12:46:06.624: E/AndroidRuntime(6332):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1551)
08-29 12:46:06.624: E/AndroidRuntime(6332):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
08-29 12:46:06.624: E/AndroidRuntime(6332):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
08-29 12:46:06.624: E/AndroidRuntime(6332):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5944)
08-29 12:46:06.624: E/AndroidRuntime(6332):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
08-29 12:46:06.624: E/AndroidRuntime(6332):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
08-29 12:46:06.624: E/AndroidRuntime(6332):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1389)
08-29 12:46:06.624: E/AndroidRuntime(6332):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1184)
08-29 12:46:06.624: E/AndroidRuntime(6332): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.location.LocationManager.removeUpdates(android.location.LocationListener)' on a null object reference
08-29 12:46:06.624: E/AndroidRuntime(6332):     at com.bustracker.TrackingService.onDestroy(TrackingService.java:301)
08-29 12:46:06.624: E/AndroidRuntime(6332):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStopService(ActivityThread.java:3339)
08-29 12:46:06.624: E/AndroidRuntime(6332):     ... 9 more
```

How can I stop the service in this two cases and why onDestroy() not being invoked when I click the button for the first time?

I appreciate any help.

**MainActivity:**

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements
        AsyncTaskCallback {
    TrackingService mService;
    boolean mBound = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.route_available);
        // Start the TrackingService class.
        Intent i = new Intent(this, TrackingService.class);
        startService(i);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
        System.out.println("test onCreateOptionsMenu was invoked.");

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuItem checkable = menu.findItem(R.id.checkable_menu);
        checkable.setChecked(isChecked);
        return true;
    }

    // Start and stop the background service.
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.checkable_menu:
            if (isChecked = !item.isChecked()) {
                item.setChecked(isChecked);
                Intent i = new Intent(this, TrackingService.class);
                startService(i);
                System.out.println("test if onOptionsItemSelected");
            } else {
                mService.stopTrackingService();

            }
            return true;

        default:
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

**TrackingService class:**

```
public class TrackingService extends Service implements AsyncTaskCallback,
        LocationListener {
    LocationManager lm;
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        detectLocation();
        return START_STICKY;
    }
    private void detectLocation() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Toast.makeText(this, "Inside detectlocation()", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
        lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 30 * 1000, 0,
                this);
        enableGPS(lm);

    }
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        lm.removeUpdates(this);
        System.out.println("ABC locationManager is not equal null.");       
    }

    public void stopTrackingService(){
        lm.removeUpdates(this);
    }
}
```

**Map activity:**

```
public class Map extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, ConnectionCallbacks, OnConnectionFailedListener{
    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
 // To stop the service when the user closed the app in the background and the map ativity was opened.      
        stopAlarm();
        Intent i = new Intent(this, TrackingService.class);
        stopService(i);
        System.out.println("ABC Map onDestroy() was invoked!");

    }

}
```

Comment: Have you tired to override BackButton and unregistered the service when clicked?

Comment: Where have I to override `onBackPressed` in the TrackingService or in the Map activity? I dont want to stop the service when I go back !

Comment: My apology what I.meant was, try to create a Variables that passes value to the Activity. E.g. in onDestroy if value = false don't unregistered the service else value = true unregistered the service.

Comment: It would be helpful if your add your apporach as answer since I dont know which `onDestroy()` do you mean?  and when should the value be true and false?

Comment: OK.I have had a quick look at the code. Since you starting the service from the MainActivity and want the service to stop only when MainActivity is destroyed then I don't think you need onDestroy in the service and just unregistered it in MainActivity onDestroy. Additionally, have a look at this link maybe it could help, perhaps you can check if the service is still running before starting it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/600207/how-to-check-if-a-service-is-running-on-android

Comment: I need `onDestroy()` in the service since when I close the app with one of the both activities the `onDestroy()` of the activity is invoked then I am using `stopService(i);` in it. Thereupon, the `onDestroy()` in the service is called and the `lm` locationManager is removed.

Comment: How can I distinguish when onDestroy() is invoked when the app is being closed and  when the user changed the activities?

Comment: Override some Activity life cycles e.g. In onResume() and/or onPause() registered, since you only want to stop the service only when application is destroyed then in will say perhaps unregistered in onStop()

Answer (score 0):

In your `MainActivity` and try something like:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    // remove locationManager here
    finish();
}
```

Comment: You mean in the Map activity?! and I dont want to stop the service when the user clicks the back button anywhere

Comment: Sorry, wrote closing not removing, I updated my answer :) You said, you want to remove your locationManager when you close the app. In this case, you have to Override the onBackPressed in your MainActivity.