# Communication between Local Service and Activity on Android

Tags: android, android-activity, android-service

I have an Activity that starts a local Service for background operation.

They both resides on the same process, so the communication between them should be simpler.

However, I don't understand how to implement the communication according to my needs:

### Activity's behavior:

- On creation, check if the service is already running:

  - If it is already running, disable Start button, and enable Stop button.
  - Otherwise, enable Start button, and disable stop button.
- When Start button pressed:
  start the service, and wait for notification from the service that it finished its internal initialization. (can take more than 10 seconds)
- When Stop button pressed: stop the service.

My problem is how to make the Activity listen to the Service without busy-waiting.

I could use IBinder according to this [link](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidServices/article.html#exercise_bindlocalservice), but I will have to busy-wait.

I will be glad for suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check this link to see if service is running
[How to check if a service is running on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/600207/how-to-check-if-a-service-is-running-on-android)
in case of communication you can use localbroadcast

Comment: Thanks alot, I will check this out.