# Same service started twice on android

Tags: android, service

I am aware that a service in android can only be started once, the doc and all relating posts I found here say the same. For some reason though, my service is listed twice in the app manager. How can that be? It is entirely the same service, since my project only contains this one.

[image]

Comment: Check before starting if service is running or not and then start if required. For info check - http://stackoverflow.com/a/5921190/2128166

Comment: Thanks, but I sorted the matter out: I was using a library that incidentally contained a service having the same name as I had chosen for mine. So one service was actually created by me, the other one by the library. Renaming my service got the confusion out of the way.