# Does calling stopService() stops all awaiting service intent

Tags: android, android-service, intentservice

In my application, I'm starting a Service multiple times even when it's running. Its a service that is perpetually running.

My question here is, when I call `stopService()`, will it stop the current running Service and ALSO clear the stack of the waiting intent? Because I want to be sure it is not running anymore.

Comment: You have an IntentService which is perpetually running ? This does not seem likely.

Comment: Your are totally right, I made a typo, it's actually a Service

Comment: Why you are starting your service multiple times , even its a Sticky service. Can you explain it, i want to think about it. There is so many ways to trigger your service methods without recreating.

Comment: I wrote it before but I erased it since it was confusing people... It's because when my app is force shutdown and reopen, I couldn't find any bulletproof solution that check if a service is still running so I ended up just calling startService again, even if it is already started... But now i'm wondering if stopService will stop it for good if there was multiple call to startService that were made. So here I don't really want to know how to check if a service is running since I already read all the solution provided here, I want to know how to stop a service that was started multiple times

Comment: This comment better than your question. Now i understand your question/problem. But i am saying again in my opinion you doing it wrongly. When you created a sticky Service it will automatically restarting when low memory etc. All you need to do is start service once and check for running in Application class , or in starter Activity.

Answer (score 0):

I dont stop my `Service`, it is `STICKY` `Service`. When starting app i am controlling the service is running or not like :

```
public static boolean isMyServiceRunning(Class<?> serviceClass,Context mContext) {
    ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    for (ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
        if (serviceClass.getName().equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Usage :

```
if(!isMyServiceRunning(MyService.class, getApplicationContext())){
       startService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));
}
```

But when i logout my user i am stopping service like :

```
Intent serviceIntent=new Intent(mContext,MyService.class);
mContext.getApplicationContext().stopService(serviceIntent);
```

Comment: I tried that one also... Makes my application crash for some particular use cases, and is not recommended by many user. See that link : http://stackoverflow.com/a/5921190/3457218

Comment: If you read that answer its sayin : "This works reliably, because it is based on the information about running services provided by the Android operating system through ActivityManager#getRunningServices." I think getting some information that provided by Android System is more reliable for me

Comment: Read through the comments there... "This method is not really sustainable. It does not work on Android KitKat.", "this method is only intended for debugging or implementing service management type user interfaces." It's not meant for control flow! "  ... I was actually using it before, until it makes my app crash

Comment: I didnt get any issue when running my app in Kitkat devices. There is no proof attached in comments. Now i have doubts about too :(

Comment: When my app crashed, it pointed to that method so I don't trust it anymore :/

Comment: I think you are right , but if you come with logs , errors and code maybe i will compare yours to mine.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113069/discussion-between-jaythaking-and-yasin-kacmaz).