# Calling startService() multiple times on a running service

Tags: android, android-service

This is just a knowledge question, I know it's not a good practice to do so. So here it is:

If I call `startService()` 3 times while it is already running, do I have to call `stopService()` 3 times to make it stop? (Does it have a stack of waiting intent?) Or just once will kill it for good?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> If I start a Service 3 times while it is already running, do I have to call stopService 3 times to make it stop?

No. One `stopService()` is sufficient.

> I know it's not a good practice to do so

Sure it is. If desired, your activity (or whatever is calling `startService()`) can blindly call `startService()` without knowing or caring whether the service is up and running. For example, if you are implementing an `IntentService` for handling downloads of mid-sized files, the activity can call `startService()` for as many downloads as the user wants. Note though that `IntentService` stops itself when it has no more work to do.

Comment: Hey, what is about we checking running services before starting service ,like my answer :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37469409/does-calling-stopservice-stops-all-awaiting-service-intent/37469513#37469513

Comment: @YasinKaçmaz: Generally, I try to avoid that pattern.

Comment: why you avoid , is there any special reason. I am using this pattern in my app and never getting error ?

Comment: @YasinKaçmaz: If the activity wants the service to be started, it calls `startService()`. If the activity wants to know information about the state of the service, use a bound service and get the status from the `Binder`, or use an event bus. I have yet to encounter a situation where the activity *only* needs to know that the service is started (which is all your approach can determine) *and* cannot just call `startService()`. You are welcome to do what you want; I just avoid your approach.

Comment: I understand , i am using eventbus too but in my service i just doing web call to update location etc. I dont need to determine situations , but like your approach. Maybe next times i need to do that. Thank you . I will favourite this question.