# Getting DeadSystemException on Samsung SMG950U (Android 8.0.0) and SM 955 (Android 8.0.0)

Tags: android, crash, samsung-mobile

I am working on a native android app & getting the following report in my Crashlytics but I am unable to figure the the exact reason for this.

I have two activities `SplashActivity` and `MapActivity` in my app. There are lot of things going on in the `MapActivity` which are a bit memory consuming.

- Getting location using `LocationManager` for getting nearby places from server.
- Fetching list of locations from server, parsing into a list (`Retrofit`)
- Generating bitmap containing dynamic text strings from list to be used for the markers (Using `AsyncTask`)
- Displaying the markers on the Google map.

**Crash Report :**

```
    java.lang.RuntimeException: android.os.DeadSystemException
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSleeping(ActivityThread.java:4403)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap23(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1893)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6938)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
    Caused by: android.os.DeadSystemException
```

**Devices affected:**

- Samsung SMG950U (Android 8.0.0)
- SM 955 (Android 8.0.0)

**What I have read already:**

- [Android DeadSystemException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42784731/android-deadsystemexception)
- [DeadSystemException start service Android 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44408197/deadsystemexception-start-service-android-7?rq=1)

Unfortunately, these links were **not** really helpful. I am sure the device wasn't restarting while it crashed. And, other apps work fine on the device. I do not own that device, I am just getting these in my Crashlytics.

If atleast I get to reproduce it on some device in the cloud for ex. using GenyMotion & get hands on the LogCat logs, it would be of great help.

Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46031036/5746918?

Comment: I have this problem primary on Samsung devices with Android 9

Comment: For us also only happening on Samsung devices, but all with Android 10

Comment: @asokBuzz Did you figure out how to fix the exception?

Comment: Did anyone find any workaround for this problem? I am facing this exception in android 10 and 86% in the background

Answer (score 0):

Probably the issue is with Samsung devices.
There is nothing you can do,its their OS problem.

You can read here.

https://forum.developer.samsung.com/t/deadsystemexception/859