# What causes DeadSystemException with ApplicationPackageManager in Android 9 and 10 Devices

Tags: android

A high number of crashes are reported in Android 9 and 10 Devices.

Below is the stacktrace:

````
    at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getPackageInfoAsUser(ApplicationPackageManager.java:264)
    at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getPackageInfo(ApplicationPackageManager.java:235)
    at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtilLight.zza(GooglePlayServicesUtilLight.java:28)
    at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtilLight.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(GooglePlayServicesUtilLight.java:22)
    at com.google.android.gms.common.GoogleApiAvailabilityLight.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(GoogleApiAvailabilityLight.java:5)
    at com.google.android.gms.common.GoogleApiAvailability.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(GoogleApiAvailability.java:94)
    at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.GoogleApiAvailabilityCache.getClientAvailability(GoogleApiAvailabilityCache.java:23)
    at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zaan.zaan(zaan.java:19)
    at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zaau.run(zaau.java:6)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:462)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
    at com.google.android.gms.common.util.concurrent.zza.run(zza.java:6)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
Caused by: android.os.DeadSystemException```
````

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android DeadSystemException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42784731/android-deadsystemexception)