# How can I stop a NotificationService from another class?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, service

I have `NotificationService` class extends `Service` and I launch the service whit method, but I don't know how to stop the current Service, I read some guide and example but with `stopService()` method I can't stop my service. This is the code of my class, how I can stop?

```
public class NotificationService extends Service {

private final long TIME_WAKE_UP = 6000;//60 * 60 * 1000;
private long timeStart;
private Esercizio es;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
    Notification mNt = mBuilder.build();
    startForeground(2, mNt);
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    timeStart = intent.getExtras().getLong("timeStart");
    es = (Esercizio) intent.getExtras().get("esercizio");

    while(System.currentTimeMillis() < timeStart + TIME_WAKE_UP);

    atWork();

    stopForeground(true);
    stopSelf();

    return START_STICKY;
}

private void atWork() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, TransitionArchive.class);
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("notificationService","");
    bundle.putString("KEY_EXCERSIZE",es.getNameEx());
    intent.putExtras(bundle);

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilderOffline =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logo_app_android)
                        .setContentTitle(es.getNameEx())
                        .setContentText("C'è un nuovo contenuto per te!")
                        .setAutoCancel(true)
                        .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX)
                        .setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,
                1,
                intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        mBuilderOffline.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        //PendingIntent call the receive class

        Notification note = mBuilderOffline.build();
        note.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
        note.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;

        NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        mNotificationManager.notify(1, note);
}

public static void startNotificationService(Context mContext, Esercizio es) {
    Intent mIntent = new Intent(mContext, NotificationService.class);
    mIntent.putExtra("esercizio", es);
    mIntent.putExtra("timeStart", System.currentTimeMillis());
    startWakefulService(mContext, mIntent);
}

@Override
@Nullable
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It may not be the best way, but I used a public static variable as a flag with an IntentService. If the flag is set, perform any necessary cleanup, stop threads, exit loops, and let it flow to stopSelf() and stopForeground() naturally (that you already have).

[How to check if a service is running on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/600207/how-to-check-if-a-service-is-running-on-android)

Comment: And how i can use this flag? i want to stop my current service from another class, not the NotificationService class

Comment: U can post the code please? where i put this static variable? i can't stop my service from another class, help me please

Comment: I updated the answer, please see the examples already provided by other users: [How to Check if a Service is Running on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/600207/how-to-check-if-a-service-is-running-on-android).

Comment: Ok but i now when the service is started, but i don't know how to kill it

Comment: From the [doc](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#Stopping), it says "a started service must manage its own lifecycle... The service must stop itself by calling stopSelf() or another component can stop it by calling stopService()" If you are using a boolean to disable the service from another class, then for any loops in the service -- test if the boolean is true and break out of the loops and then stopForeground() and stopSelf() will be stop the service.

Comment: If in my while i set if whit a static boolean and execute stopForeground() and stopSelf() my service don't sop the run, i think because my boolean is false, and boolean == true from another class don't work

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    timeStart = intent.getExtras().getLong("timeStart");
    es = (Esercizio) intent.getExtras().get("esercizio");

    while(System.currentTimeMillis() < timeStart + TIME_WAKE_UP);

    atWork();

    stopForeground(true);
    stopSelf();

    return START_NOT_STICKY;
}
```