# Android O Replacement for getRunningServices

Tags: android, android-service, android-8.0-oreo

In previous versions of Android, I used this method to find if a service from another app was up and running. It worked reliably for me:

```
ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager)getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
List<RunningServiceInfo> services = manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
```

However, with Android O, this is now deprecated and will only return information about the calling app's services. I've looked into other solutions, but I don't want to ask the user for more permissions, (UsageStatsManager, NotificationManager, etc).

Is there an alternate solution for obtaining if a service from a different app is running or not in Android O?

Comment: I doubt it. Google specifically *wants* the user to know that you have access to this sort of information (via other permissions), if you have access to it at all.

Comment: That's what I am afraid of. It seems Android is locking down this type of interaction, making apps much more siloed (without user consent). Which is good for users, but not fun for developers.

Comment: It's a specific use case I'm looking for that I need this functionality. I don't need the service to be running, but need to know if it is running.

Comment: One can use it for automated tests.

Comment: Is there any find a solution for above? please help me

Comment: Both of those questions were asked after I asked this question so they are duplicates of my question.

Answer (score 1):

It is intentional that there is **no replacement** for this function. It is not too clear from the documentation, but [from the docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#getRunningServices(int)):

> Note: this method is only intended for debugging or implementing service management type user interfaces.

Basically, using the method to check other apps services was an unintended side-effect, so Google decided to remove it. Likely for privacy/security purposes to avoid apps "sniffing" other apps/services on the user's device.

You didn't mention your use-case, but you want to avoid asking users for permissions. However, Google is intentionally forcing developers to explicitly request permissions they need, a philosophy which you can find explained [here](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2015/08/building-better-apps-with-runtime.html).

Comment: Thanks for your comment, however, after almost 3 years since the original question was posted I think it is safe to say that at the time there was no alternative and there has not been one introduced since.

Comment: Which is why I left a comment so anyone looking for an answer isn't left hanging..

Answer (score 0):

As per documentation:

```
As of O, this method is no longer available to third party applications.
For backwards compatibility, it will still return the caller's own services.
```

But may be this solution will help: [How to check if a service is running on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/600207/how-to-check-if-a-service-is-running-on-android/608600#608600)

Comment: Thanks, yes I read the documentation and that is why I was specifically asking for a replacement. As the question also states it must return a status for services from different apps, so creating a static variable as the linked solution suggests will not work.