# Is it safe to use getRunningServices() in order to get only your own services?

Tags: android, service, deprecated, android-8.0-oreo

Since getRunningServices() was deprecated in Android Oreo and after searching for a while it seems that there is no any other **right** way to obtain a list of services I' am wondering if it's safe to use this method for my **own** services and just suppress deprecation warnings. Because documentation says "Note: this method is only intended for debugging or implementing service management type user interfaces."

Comment: Does it even work? [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48506971/how-to-check-if-a-service-is-running-on-android-8-api-26) question mentioned it started returning empty list.

Comment: @Pawel It does, but it returns only your own services. Documentation says "As of Build.VERSION_CODES.O, this method is no longer available to third party applications. For backwards compatibility, it will still return the caller's own services."

Comment: Personally I stopped using it because this method had atrocious performance - but if you feel like service connection does not fill your requirements I don't see why not to use it.