# SecurityException: Not allowed to start Service

Tags: android, android-service, android-lifecycle

In our app we have a *Service* defined in this way

```
<service
    android:name="ServiceName"
    android:exported="false" />
```

When *Activity*'s `onCreate()` is called, app starts this *Service*. And everything is fine, until it is moved to background for a long time. After moving app to foreground *onCreate()* is called again, and app tries to start *Service* but gets an error:

> Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Not allowed to start service Intent { act=action_name cmp=app_bundle/service_name } without permission not exported from uid 10156

App crashes and after restart everything works again. I really can't get what is going wrong. Looks like *Activity* is started with new `uid`, but tries to interact with *Service* from another process with another `uid` (????).

Crash reproduces only on *Asus* phone, *Android* 6.0.0.

Comment: Why are you starting the service again when it is already running?

Comment: @greenapps why not? If service is running, it will just handle an intent in onStartCommand.

Answer (score 1):

> Looks like *Activity* is started with new `uid`, but tries to interact with *Service* from another process with another `uid` (????)

I believe you've answered own question.

> And everything is fine, until it is moved to background for a long time.

During the *"long time"* your app's process (with `uid` 10XXX assigned) that started the *Service* at first place could have been killed by the system. Your *Service* probably returned *START_STICKY* or a similar flag from its `onStartCommand()`, so when the app process was killed the *Service* started  within a new process, **with another `uid` assigned** by the system.

Then, when you bring your app back to foreground, it runs within a brand new process (meaning with another `uid` assigned by the system). Within one of *Activity*'s `onCreate()` you start the *Service* that has `android:exported="false"` and, since this time it is called from within another `uid`, a `SecurityException` is thrown (*such a behavior might be your Asus-phone-specific only - I recommend to check the behavior with phones from other vendors*).

Answer (score -1):

You should add a check if the service is already running in onCreate() so you won't have double entries for your service. This exception is caused by it I suppose.

One of the ways to check

```
I use the following from inside an activity:

private boolean isMyServiceRunning(Class<?> serviceClass) {
    ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    for (RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
        if (serviceClass.getName().equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

And I call it using:

```
isMyServiceRunning(MyService.class)
```

[Src](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/600207/how-to-check-if-a-service-is-running-on-android)

Comment: I will check it. But if you try to start a service, which is running, it will just handle an intent inside onStartCommand. I guess the problem here with android:exported="false", but it shouldn't exist.