# Android 12 ForegroundServiceStartNotAllowedException while in Foreground?

Tags: android, kotlin

While it seems there are a few questions on here regarding Android 12 service restrictions, I have yet to see one specific to this use case.

Background: I am starting a foreground service to handle a very long running background media player (Exoplayer). Due to the setup of the app, I cannot use the built in notification manager from exoplayer. However I am seeing an odd behavior from Crashlytics. I am getting `ForegroundServiceStartNotAllowedException` While the app is undoubtedly in the foreground. Per the logs, it is easy to see the user is navigating the app within a second of the `startForeground` call.

I am also listening to

```kotlin
override fun onStateChanged(source: LifecycleOwner, event: Lifecycle.Event)
```

to ensure the app is in a foreground state.

[image: logs]

[image: crash]

I am beginning to run out of ideas as to what would cause this. As you can see by the timestamps, less than 1 second had gone by. The app has no use cases where the service could even accidentally be started from the background.

Thanks

Edit:

I am also declaring my service type:

```xml
        <service
            android:name=".service.SoundPlayerService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false"
            android:foregroundServiceType="mediaPlayback"
            android:stopWithTask="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.media.browse.MediaBrowserService" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
```

```kotlin
        if (!audioFocusTakenBackground && Application.instance.isAppInForeground) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
                startForeground(
                    ONGOING_NOTIFICATION_ID,
                    builder.build(),
                    ServiceInfo.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_TYPE_MEDIA_PLAYBACK
                )
            } else {
                startForeground(
                    ONGOING_NOTIFICATION_ID,
                    builder.build()
                )
            }
        }
```

Edit: Device State tab suggested by @Arlind

[image: Device States]

Comment: Did you [try](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70378618/5695091) this solution?

Comment: Hi @ysfcyln I did see that comment and tried that a few versions ago. Unfortunately it seems to have no effect. I edited my question above to show that. Thanks

Comment: did you get a success on this problem?

Comment: I see a similar thing in my app. Do you receive any media button actions like KEYCODE_MEDIA_PLAY ? Then your app might be started as a reaction on this event in background. Especially Samsung devices do this nasty thing. I am still unsure how to solve it though.

Comment: @sam_k for now I put my target back down to 30. I am still looking into as to why this is happening, I only have a pixel device to test Android 12 on so it's difficult for me to debug Samsung devices. @ slezadev I will look into that. Currently my notification only allows users to stop the sound through it, not start. I'm wondering if there's some system media controls that might allow it.

Comment: There is a Device states tab in firebase crashes, that should show 100% background for this crash

Comment: @Arlind I posted that tab. Because of this too, another interesting fact is that all of them are Samsung devices running Android 12 and in the foreground

Comment: @brettywhite that crash log is for a SecurityException.
Add `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>` to the Manifest file.

Comment: @Arlind I've had that since day 1:

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />

Comment: For the SecurityException take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48930204/securityexception-not-allowed-to-start-service

Comment: For ForegroundServiceStartNotAllowedException, also please share the crash log

Comment: @brettywhite did you figure this out

Comment: @Arlind unfortunately not yet. I've kept my target at 30 and I haven't had time to play with it since.

Comment: I believe this is a bug in Android 12, it is preventing foreground services even in situations which are supposed to be allowed. You can see some discussion here https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/229000935?utm_source=pocket_mylist&pli=1

Comment: @mbwasi I think you are right. I added to the discussion there as well. Hopefully this is addressed soon since they are starting to force API 31 on google play submissions. I am definitely seeing my error count rise again

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One thing that's looking promising (I won't mark anything as answered until I get more data in) is by adding this bit to the notification builder:

```kotlin
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {
    foregroundServiceBehavior = Notification.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_IMMEDIATE
}
```

Then to prevent crashes but still be notified of an issue I wrapped the `startForeground` in a try/catch that posts to crashlytics so i know there's an issue:

```kotlin
        if (!audioFocusTakenBackground && Application.instance.isAppInForeground && !isForegroundActive) {
            isForegroundActive = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
                try {
                    startForeground(ONGOING_NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.build(), ServiceInfo.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_TYPE_MEDIA_PLAYBACK)
                    true
                } catch (e: Exception) {
                    Timber.e("Unable to start foreground: ${e.message}")
                    FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().recordException(e)
                    false
                }
            } else {
                try {
                    startForeground(ONGOING_NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.build())
                    true
                } catch (e: Exception) {
                    Timber.e("Unable to start foreground: ${e.message}")
                    FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().recordException(e)
                    false
                }
            }
        }
```

Note that in the area where `Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q`, it adds that the notification is a `FOREGROUND_SERVICE_TYPE_MEDIA_PLAYBACK`. According to the google docs here: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/foreground-services#notification-immediate this should be enough to initially show the notification. I'm curious if some implementations don't use or listen to that.

I will update this when I get more data, but for now my crashes have subsided and I am not seeing any logging from the catch blocks in crashlytics. Hopefully someone else can use this and verify my findings.

EDIT:

After a few days my crashes from this error have gone down to 0 and no noticeable logs from the catch's have been observed. Finally calling this one closed

Comment: I can't find .foregroundServiceBehavior in NotificationCompat.Builder