# Why Job services are still scheduled after app uninstall

Tags: android

I performed uninstall to an app and reboot but after checking the scheduled jobs using: `adb shell dumpsys jobscheduler` 
I still see the jobs scheduled. Why is this the behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Android maintains a service in memory after stopping it, in case it is necessary for future uses.

You can check if the service is still running:
[How to check if a service is running on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/600207/how-to-check-if-a-service-is-running-on-android/5921190#5921190)

Extra info:  Does reboot clear RAM?
https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/86645/does-reboot-clear-ram

Greetings