# Service already running while it shouldnt in Location Using Background Service code

Tags: java, android, service, location, background-service

I am having an app that has to get the location of where I am in many activities. I found this very helpful complete piece of code [here](https://deepshikhapuri.wordpress.com/2016/11/25/service-in-android/). Its how to Get Current Location Using Background Service. I implemented it in my code. The first time it worked ok. The next, when it reached this if

```
if (mPref.getString("service", "").matches("")) {
        medit.putString("service", "service").commit();
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), GoogleService.class);
        startService(intent);

 } else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Service is already running", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
```

I get the message that service is already running. Why this happens? I have closed and reopened the app, why the service still running? Help pls, its very important, thank you

Comment: `if (mPref.getString("service", "").matches("")) {` ..where are u setting this

Comment: @psypher If you see the code on the link I use it like that exactly. I'm setting it in onCreate of the activity

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if a service is running on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/600207/how-to-check-if-a-service-is-running-on-android)

Comment: I close it from the screen where you can see the  standby apps, like a user would do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `SharedPreferences` to persist the info about your `Service` then the info survives the app restart and so your `if` condition is always `false` (when you do `mPref.commit()` you save the key pair to the file).

Comment: So I shouldnt use that? What should I use instead?

Comment: @ProgrammerToBe If the service is running then your startService() won't create a new service but only invoke onStartCommand of the existing one.

Comment: @ProgrammerToBe why are you doing this check anyways? Then, I could suggest what to do instead.

Comment: Yes you are right, I just removed it and it works, thank you very much