# IntentService stop app on startService()

Tags: android, intentservice

My app crashes when I call `startService()`. The problem is that I don't get an error in the console and thus I don't know how to troubleshoot this crash.

I am looking for way to troubleshoot my problem if anybody has some leads.
I was thinking maybe I can't start a service from the onCreate method of the main activity for some reason.

I start the service from the onCreate() method of the main activity:

```
serviceIntent = new Intent(this, myIntentService.class);
        startService(serviceIntent);
```

The following is the only code I have in `myIntentService` class:

```
 public myIntentService(String name) {
        super(name);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(@Nullable Intent intent) {

        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // Restore interrupt status.
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }

        Log.v("Info", "Service " + this.getClass().getSimpleName() + " received a request");
        //executeRequest();
    }
```

If I comment the `startService()` line the app open without crashing.

I used [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/600207/how-to-check-if-a-service-is-running-on-android) to check is my service is running:

```
Log.v("Info", "Is Service "+ WhichAuthCurrentService.class.getSimpleName() + " running? response: " + isMyServiceRunning(myIntentService.class));
```

Which write in the console:

```
Is Service WhichAuthCurrentService running? response: true
```

Notes I do not implement methods, such as `onCreate()`, `onStartCommand()`, nor `onDestroy()` and I added my service to `AndroidManifest.xml`.
All the related question I found were solved by properly overwriting these method or adding the service to the Android Manifest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because you don't have a default constructor for your Service, just remove the constructor or add a default one(no parameters) and it'll magically work!

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
 public myIntentService(String name) {
        super(name);
    }
```

to:

```
 public myIntentService() {
        super("myIntentService");
    }
```