# How to run a background service in oreo to detect Voip calls

Tags: android, android-8.0-oreo

Hello everyone Iam using Sinch app for calling services in background and as they have provided with a service and if that service keeps running in the background then i keep getting incoming calls but as par Oreo restrictions its depricated and i dont want to use a foreground service either and keep a notification on , please let me know of how i can solve this problem

Answer (score -1):

You should be use workmanager or Job schedule .
Or use forground Services

Comment: but iam not using any broadcast service its jus a service class given by sinch which does all the work i jus need it running i mean the method inside it which triggers for incmng call running

Comment: Edit answer  please check it

Comment: WorkManager PeriodicWorkRequest Executes request for every 15 minutes only as per its documentation and that i cannot prefer

Comment: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51724971/unique-onetimeworkrequest-in-workmanager&ved=2ahUKEwid4IT1qdTgAhXHfCsKHa7NAB0QFjAAegQIBxAB&usg=AOvVaw3KGfaDB5gg2Dcc3zMVYdB6

Comment: foreground service needs a notification, but viber, skype, telegram don't use it