# Check if WorkManager status

Tags: android, android-workmanager

I used this example: [Check if WorkManager is scheduled already](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51612274/check-if-workmanager-is-scheduled-already)

But my code always returns false:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Log.d("DTAG", "scheduled: " + isWorkScheduled(WORKER_TAG));
    PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder myWorkBuilder = new PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(FetchFeedWorker.class, 30, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
    PeriodicWorkRequest photoCheckWork = myWorkBuilder.build();
    WorkManager instance = WorkManager.getInstance();
    instance.enqueueUniquePeriodicWork(WORKER_TAG, ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.KEEP, photoCheckWork);
    Log.d("DTAG", "scheduled: " + isWorkScheduled(WORKER_TAG));
}


private boolean isWorkScheduled(String tag) {
    WorkManager instance = WorkManager.getInstance();
    ListenableFuture<List<WorkInfo>> statuses = instance.getWorkInfosByTag(tag);
    try {
        boolean running = false;
        List<WorkInfo> workInfoList = statuses.get();
        for (WorkInfo workInfo : workInfoList) {
            WorkInfo.State state = workInfo.getState();
            running = state == WorkInfo.State.RUNNING | state == WorkInfo.State.ENQUEUED;
        }
        return running;
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}
```

Log:

```
 2020-02-24 17:45:26.352 5841-5841/com.michlindevelopment.rssreader D/DTAG: scheduled: false
 2020-02-24 17:45:26.365 5841-5841/com.michlindevelopment.rssreader D/DTAG: scheduled: false
```

Comment: And where is `Log.d("DTAG", "scheduled: " + isWorkScheduled(WORKER_TAG));` ?

Comment: Care to enlighten me....

Comment: what is your dependency, did you try 1.0.0-beta02?

Comment: "androidx.work:work-runtime:2.3.2"
"androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx:2.3.2"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are enqueuing by a unique name but looking it up by a (non-existent) tag. Use https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/WorkManager#getWorkInfosForUniqueWork(java.lang.String) instead.