# Check if a service is already running

Tags: android

I have a service that starts in my Application class in my android app.

The service runs every hour, and I do not want it to start every time the app is opened, which seems to be what its doing now.  I want to  check if it is running, and if it isnt, then run it.

[I found this code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5921190/1445985) in another answer that I thought would work, but if I run the app twice I still get the message 'Service is not running, Job Scheduled' from the below code:

```
public class App extends Application {

    public static final String TAG = "Application";
    public static final int JOB_NUMBER = 3007;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        if(!isMyServiceRunning(DevotionalService.class)) {
            ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(this, DevotionalService.class);
            JobInfo info = new JobInfo.Builder(JOB_NUMBER, componentName)
                    .setRequiresCharging(false)
                    .setRequiredNetworkType(JobInfo.NETWORK_TYPE_UNMETERED)
                    .setPersisted(true)
                    .setPeriodic(60 * 60 * 1000)
                    .build();
            JobScheduler scheduler = (JobScheduler) getSystemService(JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE);
            int resultCode = scheduler.schedule(info);
            if (resultCode == JobScheduler.RESULT_SUCCESS) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Service is not running, Job Scheduled.");
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "Service is not running, However job scheduling failed.");
            }
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "Service is already running.");
        }
    }

    private boolean isMyServiceRunning(Class<?> serviceClass) {
        ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        for (ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
            if (serviceClass.getName().equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public void cancelJob() {
        JobScheduler scheduler = (JobScheduler) getSystemService(JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE);
        scheduler.cancel(JOB_NUMBER);
        Log.d(TAG, "Job Cancelled.");
    }
}
```

Does anyone have any insight as to why this might be?

Comment: Destroying the service when the App gets killed is not an option ?

Comment: @Greggz No, it checks hourly to find out if there are new notifications etc from the website.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To check if a service is running:

```
class MyService extends Service {
   private static boolean isRunning;
   public int onStartCommand (Intent intent, 
                int flags, 
                int startId) {
        isRunning = true;
        ...
   }
   public void onDestroy() {
       isRunning = false;
   }
   public static boolean isRunning() { 
       return isRunning;
   }
}
```

Then to check if its running, just check `MyService.isRunning()`.

To check if a service is scheduled:

```
if(JobScheduler.getPendingJob(jobID) == null) {
   //job notscheduled
}
```

Comment: Hmm, interesting!! Your answer makes me think I've phrased my question incorrectly.  I dont want to know if its *running*, just if its already been scheduled to run in the future, as in, "Have I already scheduled this service?"

Comment: @Chud37 Ok, yes that's a different question altogether.  But your code sample you posted isn't going to do that either, its also looking at what's currently running.  ActivityManager.getRunningServices() knows nothing about what's scheduled in the future.

Comment: @Chud37 For what you want, try JobScheduler.getPendingJob(int jobID).  That will return non null if already scheduled.