# How to check if an Android Service is already Running

Tags: android, kotlin, android-service

This is a similar question to [How to check if a service is running on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/600207/how-to-check-if-a-service-is-running-on-android) but since the question is old and the answers provided there are deprecated or not working properly. Thus the separate question.

I have an implementation, that fires a Service on Boot Complete, but I also want to start the service in `onCreate` of MainActivity, in case the service was not started before.

**here are what I have tried:**

**1. Fetch Static Boolean to get the state of the Service as demonstrated below.**

MyService.kt

```
class MyService : Service() {
    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        isServiceStarted = true
    }
    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        isServiceStarted = false
    }
    companion object {
        var isServiceStarted = false
    }
}
```

MainActivity.kt

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(){
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val serviceStarted = MyService.isServiceStarted
        if (!serviceStarted) {
            val startMyService = Intent(this, MyService::class.java)
            ContextCompat.startForegroundService(this, startMyService)
        }
    }
}
```

but I soon discovered that `onDestroy` is not always called when a Service is destroyed, thereby leaving my static boolean variable (`isServiceStarted`) to be true, when in reality it has been destroyed.

**2.A function to check**

```
fun isMyServiceRunning(serviceClass : Class<*> ) : Boolean{
    var manager = getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE) as ActivityManager
    for (service in manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
        if (serviceClass.name.equals(service.service.className)) {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

The Call

`isMyServiceRunning(MyService::class.java)`

Problems with this approach include:
- getRunningServices is deprecated since Android O (API 27),
- It is resource consuming and inefficient to loop through running services like that and because the docs say:

> Note: this method is only intended for debugging or implementing service management type user interfaces.

It's not meant for control flow!

What is an Elegant/Efficient way to check if a Service is already running?

Comment: You can try to bind to your service **without** [`BIND_AUTO_CREATE`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#BIND_AUTO_CREATE) flag, but it's a bit more tricky because result will be not receiving `onServiceConnected` callback instead of direct boolean.

Comment: I would use method 1. The only time `onDestroy()` is not called is if your app is terminated. And when the app starts up again, `isServiceStarted` will be false, just like it is every time the app starts. If you disagree, please provide more information.

Comment: @greeble31 that's the current implementation

Answer (score 0):

If service is in the application process just use the static field inside service (companion object) or [bind](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services#Binding) to service.
If the service runs in remote process use [Messanger](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services#Messenger) if you want to have a synchronized communication or [AIDL](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/aidl.html) when you want to care about threads.