# Avoid Multiple Instances for a Service

Tags: android, service, singleton, background-service

I have created a foreground service, which is working perfectly and performs tasks in the background,
But whenever I call `startForegroundService` onCreate method is getting called.

As I know and according to [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#StartingAService), Service is a kind of singleton class but still, multiple instances are getting created.

Does anyone have any idea How can I avoid multiple instances of service??

Comment: not universal, but you may check that service is already [running by checking its own static instance or flag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/600207/how-to-check-if-a-service-is-running-on-android) (don't follow most votes ans! check out whole topic and comments)

Comment: You are most likely mistaken about the number of `Services` that are actually alive. How many times is `onDestroy()` being called? Just because some objects created by your `Service` are alive, and tasks are being executed in the background, does not mean the OS has not destroyed your `Service`. You should explain the binding scheme you are using. Are you ever calling `stopService()` or `stopSelf()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Service was getting destroyed but the handler whose instance was getting created repeatedly here.
Issue solved by removing handler in onDestroy of Service
@greeble31 Thanks for your hint