# Is this way for checking if a service is running really that bad?

Tags: java, android, android-service, android-service-binding

In my app which is a mediaplayer, i want to know if my Service is running or not.

The reason i want to know this is because i only want to **bind** my service when it's already running.

When my app is opened and a song is clicked i call the method **startMusicService** which checks if the service is already bound or not, if not then i call the method **bindMusicService**.

in **bindMusicService** i check whether mServiceIsBound is true/false, if false i then **Bind** my **Service** which then calls **onServiceConnected**.

in **onServiceConnected** i check if **serviceAlreadyRunning** is false, if so then i start playing my song.

Everything works fine, but i'm sure there is a better and more efficient way achieving the same thing.

I did it this way because if i bind my service let's say in onCreate, it already starts playing a song without selecting one.

I only want my service to be started when i select a song to play.

```
 public void bindMusicService(boolean alreadyRunning){
        //boolean alreadyRunning: if True, then we don't call startActionPlay() in onServiceConnected() because Service is already running.
        serviceAlreadyRunning = alreadyRunning;
        /*mediaPlayerServiceIntent binds our connection to the MediaPlayerService. */
        if (!mServiceIsBound) {
            try {
                mediaPlayerServiceIntent = new Intent(context, MediaPlayerService.class);
                context.bindService(mediaPlayerServiceIntent, serviceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Main", "An exception was caught: Service is not bound!");
            }
        }
    }

    public void startMusicService(int songPos, ArrayList<Song> songs){
        songIndex = songPos;
        songList = songs;
        if (mServiceIsBound) {
            mediaPlayerService.startActionPlay(context, songList, songIndex);
        }else{
            bindMusicService(false);
            Log.i("Main", "startMusicService(): Service was not bound yet, binding Service...");
 }
```

**Code in onServiceConnected**

```
public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
            MediaPlayerService.MusicBinder binder = (MediaPlayerService.MusicBinder)service;
            mediaPlayerService = binder.getService();
            if (!serviceAlreadyRunning) {
                mediaPlayerService.startActionPlay(context, songList, songIndex);
            }
            mServiceIsBound = true;
            Intent intent = new Intent(Constants.ACTIONS.BROADCAST_SERVICE_BOUND);
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(intent);

            Log.i("Main","MediaPlayerService is connected!");
   }
```

> Why is the code below considered bad? Alot of posts say that ActivityManager for checking running service only should be used for debugging purposes and not for release.

in **onResume()** i have this code:

```
if (isMyServiceRunning(MediaPlayerService.class)){
          if (!Main.getInstance().mServiceIsBound) {
                Main.getInstance().bindMusicService(true);
                Log.i(TAG, "Service already running but not bound!");
          }
          Log.i(TAG, "Service is running!");
}
```

**isMyServiceRunning method**

```
private boolean isMyServiceRunning(Class<?> serviceClass){
        ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        if (activityManager != null){
            for (ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo serviceInfo: activityManager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)){
                if (serviceClass.getName().equals(serviceInfo.service.getClassName())){
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if a service is running on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/600207/how-to-check-if-a-service-is-running-on-android)

Comment: Have you considered following the [audio app documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media-apps/audio-app/building-an-audio-app)? It goes through all of the steps for building a media app.