# How to check android service is running in background or foreground using command?

Tags: android, android-service, adb

How to check android service is running in background or foreground using command ?

Comment: may be it'll help you :https://stackoverflow.com/a/5921190.Please post your error or more information about it so the community will help you.

Comment: @ViralPatel The linked question asks about how to determine if a `Service` is running programatically. OP wants to know how to determine this using `adb` command.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `adb shell dumpsys activity services`

Foreground services should have `isForeground=true` in the output

Comment: If the answer was helpful, you should accept it by clicking the green checkmark. Or do you still have questions about this?

Comment: this is giving all services on my device but Is it possible to do only my app?

Comment: @mbpatel You can append your package name to the command, like this: `adb shell dumpsys activity services com.mycompany.mypackage`