# Is it possible to have multiple instances of the same service?

Tags: android

In Android, is there any way to run multiple instances of the same service?

If it is possible, how can you prevent multiple instances?

Comment: If you literally mean the same subclass of `Service`, then no. Only one instance of a `Service` will be running at a time in an app.

Comment: But you can call same service multiple times..

Comment: you can prevent multiple instances by checking service is running Or not...  https://stackoverflow.com/a/5921190/2293855