# Unable to convert Java to Kotlin, getting 'Name expected' error?

Tags: java, kotlin

I am trying to convert this code  to Kotlin:

```
  private boolean isMyServiceRunning(Class<?> serviceClass) {
    ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    for (ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
      if (serviceClass.getName().equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }

System.out.println(isMyServiceRunning(ExampleService.class));
```

Here's what I tried but it's still wrong because I get error `Name expected` in the last line:

```
  private fun isMyServiceRunning(serviceClass: Class<*>): Boolean {
    val manager = getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE) as ActivityManager
    for (service in manager.getRunningServices(Int.MAX_VALUE)) {
      if (serviceClass.name == service.service.className) {
        return true
      }
    }
    return false
  }


System.out.println(isMyServiceRunning(ExampleService.class))
```

Please tell me how to fix it. Original code is from here :https://stackoverflow.com/a/5921190/13976983

Comment: try doing ExampleService::javaClass

Comment: @Plee now i get `type mismatch`

Comment: Can you please add a comment indicating where the error is. Can you also post the full error?

Comment: Use `ExampleService::class.java`. You can also replace the last six lines of your function with `return manager.getRunningServices(Int.MAX_VALUE).any { it.service.className == serviceClass.name }`

Comment: @Tenfour04 ok. now I get this weird error: 

Circular dependency between the following tasks:
:mylib:generateDebugRFile
\--- :mylib:generateDebugRFile (*)

(*) - details omitted (listed previously)

Comment: I don't recognize those names and they seem to have nothing to do with the code above.